# Need some examples of binding attributes in custom AngularJS tags

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to create a custom tag similar to the following:

```
<mytag type="Big" />
```

where type is an attribute that gets bound to the component. in such a way that it sets the text in a label, as shown below:

```
<label>{{type}}</label>
```

... (other components)...

As the documentation says, I have a controller that sets a default type:

```
$scope.type = "Small";
```

so that if I use my tag without the attribute type still gets set.

I am attempting to do binding using a directive:

```
angular.module('TestPage',[])
      .directive('mytag',function() {
          return {
              restrict: 'E',
              templateUrl: 'component.html',
              scope: {
                  type: '='
              }
          }
      });
```

Note that I do have the appropriate ng-app settings in my component template (ng-app="TestPage").

My problem is that the binding to type does not appear to be actually binding anything.

I have read the documentation about how to bind a variable to components using directive. According to the documentation, you can do such bindings inside a scope. Scopes apparently can contain an "object-hash" (whatever that is!) which creates something called an "isolate scope" (???). Such scopes can represent "local properties" in the following ways:

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the DOM attribute. The result is always a string 
>   since DOM attributes are strings. If no attr name is specified then the local name and 
>   attribute name are same. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' }, then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the parent scope (not component scope).

Huh??? What has all this to do with the proper syntax for binding?

> = or =expression - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent
>    scope property. If no attr name is specified then the local name and attribute name are same. 
>    Given  and widget definition of scope: { localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localName will reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in localModel will reflect in parentModel.

Excuse me? What is being said here???

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no 
>    attr name is specified then the local name and attribute name are same. Given 
>     and widget definition of scope: { localFn:'increment()' },
>    then isolate scope property localFn will point to a function wrapper for the increment() expression. Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolate scope via an expression and to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

Now I'm totally confused! You have widget tags and some kind of related function that I have to write iin order to do the bind??? All I want is to bind a value to a label tag!

I have copied the above text from the documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to make a point: that this doco reads like the old UNIX documentation: really useful to those who already know the system, but not so helpful to beginners who are trying to develop real expertise. With all the tutorials that show how to do simple tasks in AngularJS (great for toy apps but not so good for the kinds of client- side applications I want to build), why aren't there any for the more advanced stuff???

Okay, time for me to be more constructive.

Can someone please provide some nice, simple examples of how to do the various bindings that this documentation is trying so hard to describe??? Examples that show the proper syntax for these scope statements and descriptions (in plain English) of exactly how they go back to the attribute being added to the custom tag???

Thank you for your patience and thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I have made a [blog post](http://dicasdolampada.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/reusable-components-with-angularjs/) about this: I think this topic should be in the official tutorial - having reusable components is a killer feature. I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/pull/50) for that

Comment: You're not alone with these frustrations. I have certainly felt this way. To those who read this and feel similarly, though, just a word of encouragement: hang in there. I'm not an Angular fanboy or enthusiast, but once I made it over the hump, I really started enjoying building with it. (Same goes for UNIX! ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Youre pretty close..

```
app.directive('mytag',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>' +
            '<input ng-model="controltype"/>' + 
            '<button ng-click="controlfunc()">Parent Func</button>' + 
            '<p>{{controlval}}</p>' + 
         '</div>',
        scope: {
            /* make typeattribute="whatever" bind two-ways (=)
            $scope.whatever from the parent to $scope.controltype
            on this directive's scope */
            controltype: '=typeattribute',
            /* reference a function from the parent through
               funcattribute="somefunc()" and stick it our
               directive's scope in $scope.controlfunc */
            controlfunc: '&funcattribute',
            /* pass a string value into the directive */
            controlval: '@valattribute'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {                  
        }
    };
});

  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
       <!-- your directive -->
       <mytag typeattribute="parenttype" funcattribute="parentFn()" valattribute="Wee, I'm a value"></mytag>
       <!-- write out your scope value -->
       {{parenttype}}
  </div>


  app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope){ 
       $scope.parenttype = 'FOO';
       $scope.parentFn = function() {
           $scope.parenttype += '!!!!';
       }
  });
```

The magic is mostly in the `scope:` declaration in your directive definition.  having any `scope: {}` in there will "isolate" the scope from the parent, meaning it gets it's own scope... without that, it would use the parent's scope.  The rest of the magic is in the scope's properties:   `scope: { 'internalScopeProperty' : '=externalAttributeName' }`... where the `=` represents a two way binding scenario. If you change that `=` to a `@` you'll see it just allows you to pass a string as an attribute to the directive. The `&` is for executing functions from the parent scope's context.

I hope that helps.

---

**EDIT: [Here is a working PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJCVe6)**

Comment: Thank you for this post. The example code was very helpful. Unfortunately I cannot seem to duplicate your example. I do have some questions: the empty "controller" function in your directive declaration does not seem to do anything. Is it related to the function declared in app.controller? Also: how exactly is app declared? I declared the directive using angular.module(). Do you use a similar statement for "app"?

Comment: app would be your module... `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);` ... sorry, it's sort of a standard variable name for the main module.

Comment: The empty `controller` function is the controller for the directive. OR... the controller for what's in the `template`.

Comment: The `$scope` in the `controller` part of your directive is a scope that is specific to that directive, and it is the scope that was defined in the `scope` parameter of the directive declaration.`

Comment: Sorry, Blesh, for my ignorance of Javascript variables. My expertise is in Java, C++, and C# programming. I am not a Javascript expert. I also do some Actionscript programming, but Actionscript is far more "complete" than Javascript... In any event, thanks for the clarification. A question: in order to use AngularJS does one have to be an expert in Javascript? I am pretty good with jQuery without having to know Javascript internals. Is this true for AngularJS or does one have to be a real Javascript expert to use it well?

Comment: To do client side development in general, it's a good idea to get some expertise in JavaScript. My background is in C#, Java, and ActionScript as well. I assure you that ActionScript is no more "complete" than JavaScript, you can do anything in JavaScript you can do in ActionScript there are just fewer keywords. ;) The main thing to know is that JavaScript is definitely it's own very complete, very capable language, and it's just very different from C# or Java. As such, you can't think of JavaScript in terms of Java or C#, you have to think of it in its own terms.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a link to a working example... also There was a typo in there... it should have been `template` not `templateUrl`

Comment: Got it. The example appears to work now. I actually should have noticed the typo...

Comment: BTW: Javascript **isn't** as complete as Actionscript because despite being an object oriented language (which it actually is)Javascript has no syntax for classes, inheritance, etc. This has nothing to do with what you can or cannot do with the language. It has to do with the features offered with the language syntax.

Comment: You can create classes with JavaScript. You can use inheritance with JavaScript. JavaScript is complete. It's just hard to understand when you're used to Java and C#. I went through the same line of thought back in the day.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't create classes in Javascript (I do it all the time!). I said that it does not have a syntax for classes. This alone makes it incomplete. Add the lack of the concept of private, protected, etc, and lack of an inheritance engine. You can implement inheritance in Javascript, you can even play scope games and make variables in an object effectively private. The fact that you have to implement and play scope games at all makes the language incomplete. A complete language (C++, C#, Java, Groovy, Scala, Ruby) does not require such efforts. Javascript is incomplete. Period.

Comment: Well. We disagree. Was my answer sufficient for your question?

Comment: Yes, your answer was sufficient, even if you have much to understand about "complete" OO languages. Whether Javascript is complete or not is not just a matter of opinion. You can show its completeness by providing the following info: 1) what keyword in Javascript is used to declare a class? 2) What Javascript keywords  declare private/protected variables? 3)what is the *built- in* syntax for declaring a subclass? These and other *built- in* supports make OO languages "complete". Without them, any so- called OO language is incomplete, regardless of people's opinions...

Answer (score 66):

I struggled a bit with this documentation too when first getting into angular, but I will make an attempt try to clarify things for you. First, when using this `scope` property, it creates an "isolated scope." All this means is that it won't inherit any properties from parent scopes, and so you don't have to worry about any collisions within the scope.

Now, the '@' notation means that the evaluated value in the attribute will automatically get bound into your scope for the directive. So, `<my-directive foo="bar" />` would end up with the scope having a property called `foo` that holds the string "bar". You could also do something like `<my-directive foo="{{bar}}"` And then the evaluated value of `{{bar}}` will be bound to the scope. Since attributes are always strings, you will always end up with a string for this property in the scope when using this notation.

The '=' notation basically provides a mechanism for passing an object into your directive. It always pulls this from the parent scope of the directive, so this attribute will never have the `{{}}`. So, if you have `<my-directive foo="bar" />` it will bind whatever is in `$scope.bar` into your directive in the `foo` property of your directive's scope. Any change's you make to `foo` within your scope will be refelected in `bar` in the parent scope, and vice versa.

I haven't used the '&' notation nearly as much as the other too, so I don't know it as well as those two. From what I understand, it allows you to evaluate expressions from the context of the parent scope. So if you have something like `<my-directive foo="doStuff()" />`, whenever you call scope.foo() within your directive, it will call the doStuff function in the directive's parent scope. I'm sure there's a lot more you can do with this, but I'm not as familiar with it all. Maybe someone else can explain this one in more detail.

If just the symbol is set in the scope, it will use the same name as the attribute to bind to the directives scope. For example:

```
scope: {
   foo1: '@',
   foo2: '=',
   foo3: '&'
}
```

When including the directive, there would need to be the attributes foo1, foo2, and foo3. If you want a property in your scope different than the attribute name, you can specify that after the symbol. So, the example above would be

```
scope: {
   foo1: '@bar1',
   foo2: '=bar2',
   foo3: '&bar3'
}
```

When including the directive, there would need to be the attributes bar1, bar2, and bar3, and these would get bound in the scope under properties foo1, foo2, and foo3 respectively.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask questions with which I can clarify my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I now have a greater understanding of the various symbols and how they work. This was very helpful.

Comment: I wonder why it's hard to find documentation saying that = is for passing an object in. All of the documentation I've read just says that = is for binding to a model value, which is less general. It doesn't need to be a model value - any expression works.