# what advantage is there when using the different types of angularjs scope bindings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when declaring scopes for directives, I have come across the symbols '@', '='.

I'm curious when would be a case where '=' bindings are perferred over '@' and vice-versa.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13033249/215945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), you can read :

> 1. @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>      strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is
>      assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' },
>      then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated
>      value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the
>      localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the
>      parent scope (not component scope).
> 2. = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>      of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute
>      name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>      localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will
>      reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to
>      parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in
>      localModel will reflect in parentModel.

So if you want a 2-way binding, you should use `=`...