# AngularJS best practice to inherit scope in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From Directives documentation it says to inherit scope in this two ways:

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>   strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is
>   assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' },
>   then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated
>   value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the
>   localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the
>   parent scope (not component scope).
>
> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute
>   name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will
>   reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to
>   parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in
>   localModel will reflect in parentModel.

Considering that i want to pass elementId, which is just an id, I can pass it through =elementId or @elementId.

Now which one of the two is considered best practice? If I use the `@` and therefore the attribute, it will take the value from the DOM which is slower than taking directly the value?

Am I correct? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If the directive needs to change the value, use = to get bi-directional binding.
- If you want to make it clear to other people reading your code that you are only using one-way binding, use @.
- If you need access to the value in the linking function synchronously, use = (see note about @ and $observe's asynchronous behavior [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives)).

For your case, @ seems best.  (An example of how you would use the directive and elementID in an HTML element would be helpful though.)

I have no idea which is slower/faster.

See also [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

Comment: +1 I'd add... "if you're having memory issues, don't isolate the scope, but set up your $watches and DOM manipulations manually in your linking function".

Comment: @blesh, good point.  I should have mentioned that you don't have to use an isolate scope (`scope: { ... }`) or even a non-isolate, new scope (`scope: true`) -- you could just use the existing scope.

Comment: isolating the scope makes it reusable I think :)