# AngularJS - Directive events and DOM rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In the code below, I am trying to use a template (with `{{ value }}` substitution) but I have been trying for two days to find a way of getting to the rendered code to set some properties on it.

I cannot use the style selector (which works fine), I need to use the div's id. In my real code I use a `templateUrl:`, not the inline code, but it has the same result.

Which event should I be listening for? At what point in time will the selectors work? I have read about compiling and linking and think the answer is out there somewhere?

Thanks in advance ...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>My AngularJS App</title>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
      <tls-window window-id="fred" window-width="600" window-label-width="150"></tls-window>
      <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/core/services.js"></script>
      <script src="js/core/controllers.js"></script>
      <script src="js/core/filters.js"></script>
      <script src="js/core/directives.js"></script>
      <script src="js/core/tlscore-directives.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      var coreDirectives = angular.module('tlsCore.directives', []);
      coreDirectives.directive('tlsWindow', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            windowId: '@windowId',
            windowWidth: '@windowWidth',
            labelWidth: '@windowLabelWidth'
          },
          replace: true,
          transclude: false,
          template: '<div id="{{windowId}}" class="tls-window" ng-cloak tls-draggable >' +
            '<div id="{{windowId}}-winBackground" class="tls-window-background" style="width: 300px; height: 200px" >' +
            '<div id="{{windowId}}-winToolbarBackground" class="tls-window-toolbar-background">' +
            '<div id="{{windowId}}-winToolbarContent" class="tls-window-toolbar-content" style="width: 300px; height: 100px">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var ele = element.get(element.index(scope.windowId));
            // this works and sets the colour (by class)
            $('.tls-window-toolbar-content').css("background-color", 'red');
            // this does not work as the id of the element is not yet substituted and rendered ??
            $('#fred-winBackground').css("background-color", 'green');
          }
        }
      });   

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want to do children dom manipulation i will recommend you replace link with prelink and postlink functions and do the dom manipulation in postlink function

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 - Better

Instead of using the `template` method, move the HTML into the `link` method. This enables us to manually `$interpolate` the bracketed terms before compiling, and then use the ID selector. Note that this would not be possible without using the `=` instead of `@` isolate scope binding, because `@` bindings are postponed until later and are undefined in the `link` method (See more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111016/angularjs-access-isolated-scope-in-directives-link-function/17111741#17111741)).

```
app.directive('tlsWindow', function($interpolate,$compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        windowId: '=',
        windowWidth: '=',
        labelWidth: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var template = '<div id="{{windowId}}" class="tls-window" ng-cloak tls-draggable >' +
        '<div id="{{windowId}}-winBackground" class="tls-window-background" style="width: 300px; height: 200px" >' +
            '<div id="{{windowId}}-winToolbarBackground" class="tls-window-toolbar-background">' +
                '<div id="{{windowId}}-winToolbarContent" class="tls-window-toolbar-content" style="width: 300px; height: 100px">' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

        var interpolated = $interpolate(template)(scope);
        var html = $(interpolated);
        element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
        
        $('.tls-window-toolbar-content').css('background-color', 'red');
        $('#fred-winBackground').css('background-color', 'green');
    }   
  }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/9BKpG/)

---

## Option 2

Not the most robust solution but this would work also. Here the manipulation is postponed until after the rendering by using `$timeout`. This causes a slight delay as well.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $('#fred-winBackground').css("background-color", 'green');
},0);
```

This requires `$timeout` to be injected into the directive as well.

Comment: Many thanks. I thought it was a timing issue but could not see how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an answer about *why* the id isn't available at link time, but might I question the reason to use an id selector at all? Once you have your directive, you can get access to the top level div in your template via the `children` method of the jqLite/jquery element in the link function. See this example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('tlsWindow', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            windowId: '@windowId',
            windowWidth: '@windowWidth',
            labelWidth: '@windowLabelWidth'
          },
          replace: true,
          transclude: false,
          template: '<div id="{{windowId}}" class="tls-window" ng-cloak tls-draggable >' +
            '<div id="{{windowId}}-winBackground" class="tls-window-background" style="width: 300px; height: 200px" >' +
            '<div id="{{windowId}}-winToolbarBackground" class="tls-window-toolbar-background">' +
            '<div id="{{windowId}}-winToolbarContent" class="tls-window-toolbar-content" style="width: 300px; height: 100px">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // var ele = element.get(element.index(scope.windowId));
            // this works and sets the colour (by class)
            // $('.tls-window-toolbar-content').css("background-color", 'red');
            // this does not work as the id of the element is not yet substituted and rendered ??
            // $('#fred-winBackground').css("background-color", 'green');
            
            // Use the jqlite or jquery children method to locate the first child of your directive
            // element (from linkFn) is the element of tls-window and children() gets you access to the <div> container in your template
            element.children().css("background-color", "green");
          }
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <tls-window window-id="fred" window-width="600" window-label-width="150"></tls-window>
</div>
```

angularjs discourages referencing elements through id selectors. Make use of jqLite/jquery methods through the context of element that is passed to the link function.