# Why didn't the link function in my AngularJS directive run?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is the HTML and Javascript for a simple Angular JS example. In this example, why didn't the link function run and set `scope.flag` to be `true` (boolean) instead of `'true'` (string)?

Javascript:

```
angular.module('truthyTypes', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
      template: '<div>flag value: {{ flag }}<br/>flag type: {{ flag | typeOf }}</div>',
      scope: {
        flag: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope){
        scope.flag = scope.flag === 'true';
      }
    }
  })
  .filter('typeOf', function(){
    return function(input){
      return typeof input;
    }
  })
;
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example78-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="truthyTypes">
    <div my-directive flag="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Live Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jqk5529FmdGsxK6Xj8LZ?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Access isolated scope in directive's link function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111016/angularjs-access-isolated-scope-in-directives-link-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using one-way binding, hence any updates you make to the flag variable in the directive won't be propagated back to the controller.

Use two-way bindings (= instead of @), to change the flag value:

```
scope: {
    flag: '='
}
```

Inside the link function, you can then set the flag to any appropriate value, e.g.

```
scope.flag = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The isolated scope is not immediately available to the link function. Please have a look at the answer to this similar question: [AngularJS - Access isolated scope in directive's link function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111016/angularjs-access-isolated-scope-in-directives-link-function)