# Scope inheritance for angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've created a tab control using angular directives. It is consist of **tab**, **tab-item**  directives with new scope and **tab-item-header**, **tab-item-body** directives for which scope is not declared.

If I understand correctly these directives use scope of tab-item directive because they are placed inside it. But when I try to get in markup property index which is declared inside tab-item scope it is undefined.

```
app.directive('tabItemHeader', function(){
return {
    require: '^tabItem',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-click="$parent.setCurrentTab(index)" ng-transclude></div>',
};});

app.directive('tabItemBody', function(){
return {
    require: '^tabItem',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-show="index==$parent.currentTabIndex"><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
};});
```

I've created a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/HkXIOt8FKMw4Ja2GZtF1?p=preview to demonstrate it.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(EDIT) Giving some thought after the conversation in the comments, I came up with a better solution. Here is the modified plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/djNk8PPzXvngZOvAirMu?p=preview

The key points of this implementation are:

- Every directive transcludes its content. This means that, even the innermost directives have access to the outer scope, as is expected. So no more `$parent.$parent...` awfulness.
- Every directive has an isolated scope. As per the docs the isolated scope is side-by-side with the transcluded one; therefore all the private state of the directives (in this case the active tab, the index of each `tabItem` and some directive-specific functions) is kept in the isolated scope.
- The directives communicate through the controllers. This pattern requires a top level "coordinator" (here the `tab` for all descendant directives and the `tabItem` for the `tabItemHeader` and `tabItemBody`).

By the way, if you want tabs, I would suggest Angular UI.

---

This was a crazy puzzler.

The reason for your problem is that the `tabItem` directive had no reason to transclude its contents; this transclusion created a sibling scope that totally messed up your logic!

Thus the answer is simple: remove these lines from the `tabItem` directive:

```
// REMOVE THEM!!!
transclude: true,
template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
```

A plunkr with these lines commented out that prints scope ids: http://plnkr.co/edit/bBfEej145s1YjcE9n3Lj?p=preview (this helps with debugging; see what happens when you include these lines, the templates and the linker function see different scopes!)

And your plunkr forked, with those lines commented out: http://plnkr.co/edit/tgZqjZk0bRCyZiHKM0Sy?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nikos!
And I want to ask you one more question about this code. For now directive's scope override controller's scope and I should use controller's variables in this way {{$parent.$parent.$parent.name}}. But it looks terrible. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually I just removed `$parent` from your plunkr (i.e. `template: '<div ng-click="setCurrentTab(index)" ...>`) and it works. Can you do that and verify it actually works? (There were some network instabilities and I have doubts)

Comment: Yes. It is possible to remove $parent from directive template. And I've fixed it. But when I want to use `name` property of the controller inside `tab-item-body` directive i should write the following: {{$parent.$parent.$parent.name}} (please see the first plunk). My question is if there is a way to do this without referencing parent scope?

Comment: Yes, still a puzzler! One answer is to remove the scope from the `tab` directive. And use directly the variable of the parent scope (Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Of2kIcaGs7DLHyYi2mAK?p=preview).

Comment: I've already thought about this solution but still try to find another. If I will find something else I leave a comment here. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: I gave some thought and you are very right. Please see the edit at the top for a better solution - the way you originally wanted it.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

This site explains scope inheritance very well.

Basically, if you add a scope section to the directive that you want to have you have a few options:

```
scope: false # this inherits the parent scope and allows upstream and downstream traffic (parent <=> child)
scope: true # this inherits the parent scope and allows downstream traffic (parent => child)
scope: {} # this does not inherit and creates the directive's very own scope (you can still inherit by specifying what you want to come down)
```

More details on specifying scope to inherit via the last option: [What is the difference between & vs @ and = in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs)