# What is the default for AngularJS directive scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

What is the default scope value of an AngularJS directive?

Of course, it is not isolated scope. It is true or false.

I can't find any documentation on what it is.

Comment: Default value of the scope is same as of the element on which the directive is invoke

Comment: if I give no value to scope, will this create a new prototypically inherited scope? or will it use the scope of the element as its scope?

Comment: @AladdinMhemed: No.  If you give no value, the default is equivalent to setting `scope: false`, which means to not create a new scope (essentially, it will "use the scope of the element as its scope", as you said)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> "Note, by default, directives do not create new scope -- i.e., the default is `scope: false`"

from [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Using the scope option in directive you can:

- create a child scope prototypically inherited with `scope: true`
- create an isolated scope with `scope: {}` then you can bind some property to parent scopes  with `'@', '&', '='` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs)).
- decide to not create a new scope and use parent with `scope: false` (default).

Comment: Would be nice if this were in their api docs (currently found at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Answer (score 0):

By default, directives shared the scope of the containing controller. 
You can specify `scope:true` to have a inherited scope and to get a isolated scope you have to do the following

```
scope:{
something1:"@",
something2:"="
something3:"&"
}
```