# Difference between the following two AngularJS constructs, if any?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Method 1**

In HTML:

```html
<my-directive>
</my-directive>
```

In Scripts:

```js
function myDirective() {
    var ddo = {
        [LOTS OF OTHER VERY IMPORTANT DIRECTIVE PROPERTIES HERE]
        controller: myController
        bindToController: true
    };
    return ddo;
}
```

**Method 2**

In HTML:

```html
<my-directive ng-controller="myController">
</my-directive>
```

In Scripts:

```js
function myDirective() {
    var ddo = {
        [LOTS OF VERY IMPORTANT DIRECTIVE PROPERTIES HERE]
    };
    return ddo;
}
```

Both cases there is a directive with some other properties (template, etc.) but I am just changing where I put controller. Are the two methods analogous?

Comment: The two answers and my replies were deleted suddenly... oh well thanks anyway

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Two answers to my post, both in the same spirit, saying that:

Comment: In the first case it is a directive, in the second it is simply a tag. I had phrased my question badly which is why they gave those replies but I have since fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, first method is preferred.

Difference is in how angular treats scopes.

Second method makes directive dependent on external scope (created by `ng-controller="myController"`) which is against the point of creating directive (code isolation).

Second method will work the same when you use parents scope (by default, when you don't set `scope` property in directive DDO - [Ref: What is default Angular directive scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033354/what-is-the-default-for-angularjs-directive-scope))

Second method won't work if you have isolated scope in directive, created like this:

```
scope: {
    param1: "="
}
```

As you won't be able access properties from `myController`.

---

**Edit**:

Directives rules might be complicated to understand all cases, consider using `.component()` as it has much simpler and follows best practices - [Introduction to Angular's components](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/).

---

**Further reading:**

- [Binding to Directive Controllers in Angular 1.3+](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html)

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!

Comment: One more follow up, does this mean that there is a difference between creating a directive with *no* scope attribute versus creating it with the scope attribute set to an empty object?

Comment: @user7339019 - yes, `scope` parameter tooks two values, true/false or object. If there is object (even empty) scope is isolated and you cannot access properties from parents scopes. 

If `scope` is set to false or just skipped in DDO, directive doesn't create new scope.