# Angularjs: how to read object in Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have passed an object from controller to directive but when i am reading object in directive i am not able to, it seems in directive object is being read as string.Code is below , i wane to read City and State from the object.

```
Html File

<div ng-controller="WeatherController">    
<div weather ng-object="{{Object}}"></div>
</div>

Controller
.controller('WeatherController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.webpartData.OverviewData.Person.Address.City;
            $scope.Object = {
                City: '',
                State: ''
            };
            $scope.Object.City = 'TestCity';
            $scope.Object.State = 'TestState';         
        });
    })
}])


Directive


angular.module('WeatherModule', [])
.directive('Weather', ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div id="weather"></div>',
        scope: {
            ngObject: '@ngObject'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('ngObject', function(value) {
                scope.ngObject = value;
            });
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log('Location' + scope.Object.City + ',' + scope.Object.State);
            }, 100);
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: at the moment i see object is diplaying as {"City":"TestCity","State":"TestState"}

Which is not readable by scope.Object.City and scope.Object.State

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "=" instead "@". And ng-object="Object" instead ng-object="{{Object}}".

Answer (score 6):

There are differences between `@, = and &` in referencing the directive scope members.

```
 1. "@"   (Text binding / one-way binding)
 2. "="   (Direct model binding / two-way binding)
 3. "&"   (Behaviour binding / Method binding)
```

**@ means that the changes from the controller scope will be reflected in the directive scope** but if you modify the value in the directive scope, the controller scope variable **will not get affected**.

**@ always expects the mapped attribute to be an expression**. This is very important; because to make the “@” prefix work, we need to wrap the attribute value inside {{}}.

**= is birectional** so if you change the variable in directive scope, the controller scope variable gets affected as well

**& is used to bind controller scope method** so that if needed we can call it from the directive

In your case you may need to use `=`  instead of `@`

Have a look on the following fiddle (It's not mine, but it have good and to the point illustration) http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/QrCXh/

**Some Related Questions also:**

- [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)
- [What is the difference between & vs @ and = in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs)