# angular directive one way binding changing value in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular one-way-binding from controller to directive. When i update value in directive, it should not update the value in controller. But it is working as two-way binding. can some one find my error.

```
angular.module("myApp",[])  
  .directive("myDirective",['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      scope: {myValue: "&myAttribute"},
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myValue().name">',
      link: function (scope, iElm, iAttrs) {
        var x = scope.myValue();
        console.log(x);
        $timeout(function(){
          x.name= "directive";
        },4000);
      }
    };
  }]).controller("myController", function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.someObject = {name: "test"};
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.someObject.name= "controller";
    },2000);

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9wihx1VYgKoTK00awN67?p=preview

Comment: I think the ampersand is going to create a function that returns the value of someObject in the parent scope, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile, so this is not one-way.

Comment: Yes, & returns a getter function. so it should be one-way

Comment: It's getting a reference to an object, though, so the directive and the parent scope both have the same reference, and any changes to the object properties will naturally show up in both places

Comment: Digressing a bit, but if you're using Angular 1.5.x, you'll have available to you the `<` binding, which is one-way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is an easier way but you could use one-way binding with `@` binding in isolated scope and add an observer on the attribute to update the object in the directive on changes.

The `@` binding takes the data from the parent and pass them as string to the directive. To create an object you have to use `scope.$eval(interpolatedStrValue)`.

(The Ampersand binding is not working as mentioned in the other answer because the getter is passing the reference to the parent object. So any change will update the parent as well.)

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/xzzzpgvf/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .directive('oneWay', OneWay)
  .controller('mainController', MainController);
  

function OneWay($timeout, $parse) {
 return {
   scope: {
     myValue: '@myAttribute'
    },
   template: '<input type="text" ng-model="myValue.name"/>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     console.log('link', scope.myValue);
      attrs.$observe('myAttribute', function(myValStr) {
       scope.myValue = scope.$eval(myValStr);
        console.log('controller myValue obj', scope.myValue);
      });
      
      $timeout(function() {
       console.log('change dir');
        scope.myValue.name = "directive changed";
       }, 4000);
      
      
    }
  }
}

function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
 $scope.testObj = {
   name: 'before mod.'
  };
  
  $timeout(function() {
   $scope.testObj.name = 'Controller modify';
  }, 2000);
  
  $timeout(function() {
   $scope.testObj.name = '2nd Controller modify';
  }, 8000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  Controller: {{testObj.name}}<br/>
  Directive: <one-way my-attribute="{{testObj}}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "@" instead of "&" like below

```
scope: {myValue: "@myAttribute"}
```

The below link explains

[What is the difference between & vs @ and = in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs)

Comment: using an @ symbol means you will only get a string value, so the template would have to look like <directive my-attr="{{ someObject.name }}"...>

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs (for 1.xx) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile ampersand is going to return the value of the attribute expression executed in the parent scope ( a getter ), which in this case is an object reference, and changes to any of the object properties will be reflected in both.

Changes to myValue in the directive scope won't affect the parent scope, though.