# Angular 1.x directive scope

Tags: angularjs

I want to transform the scoped variable, like trimming the passed string.
but it shows always as it passed.

here is my sample code,

```
export function testDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: `<a>{{vm.testText}}</a>`,
        scope: {
            testText: '@'
        },
        controller: TestController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    }
}

export class TestController {
    testText: string;

    constructor(private $scope: angular.IScope) {
        // when getting variable, I need to transform the value
        $scope.$watch( () => this.testText, (newVal: string) => {
            this.testText = newVal.trim() + ' Edited'; // this doesn't affact
        });
    }
}
```

why that code is not working?

To make it work I added additional variable(trimmedText), but I don't think this is right approach,

```
export function testDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: `<a>{{vm.trimmedText}}</a>`,
        scope: {
            testText: '@'
        },
        controller: TestController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    }
}

export class TestController {
    testText: string;
    trimmedText: string;

    constructor(private $scope: angular.IScope) {
        // when getting variable, I need to transform the value
        $scope.$watch( () => this.testText, (newVal: string) => {
            this.trimmedText = newVal.trim() + ' Edited'; // it works
        });
    }
}
```

Please advice me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Expert wanna be, using the `=` sign in the isolated scope of the directive definition sets up two way data binding within the directive.

Check the below code snippet, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/me04dgvz/) the jsfiddle link.You can find more information about the different types of data binding in directives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs)

The HTML

```
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <custom-directive test-text="ctrl.text"></custom-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Angular code

```
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .controller('CustomDirectiveController', CustomDirectiveController)
  .directive('customDirective', customDirective);

  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.text = 'Hello, ';
  }

  function customDirective() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: `<a href="#">{{vm.testText}}</a>`,
      scope: {
        testText: '='
      },
      controller: CustomDirectiveController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
  }

  function CustomDirectiveController() {
    var vm = this;
    // transforming/updating the value here
    vm.testText = vm.testText + 'World!';
  }
```

Comment: @Expert wanna be, looks like you're using the modern component-based architecture that Angular 2 follows along with ES2015/ES6, I'll try to learn using Angular 2 pattern in Angular 1 today and include an e.g. using Angular 2 pattern in my answer, as this course is free for the weekend https://egghead.io/courses/using-angular-2-patterns-in-angular-1-x-apps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment, So to use '=', I should pass a object, not a string!

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch( () => this.testText, // <-- use this.textText here
```

Comment: Sorry that was mistypo error ;( That doesn't update view

Answer (score 0):

'@' is not right binding, if you want to modify it - use '='.
But using additional variable is actually correct approach.

Another good way for simple transformation is using filter.

Comment: If I change to '=', I got this error, Lexer Error: Unexpected nextharacter  at columns 0-0...