# How to pass changed variable from Child component to Parent component without using @Output?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm not able to figure out how to use two way binding in angular 4 directive.

In AngularJs I used to do it like this:

```
<random-directive binded='name' binded2="xyz"></random-directive>
```

And in directive definition add `=` after name. And now I can change `name` from the directive controller or `link`.

But in `Angular 2-6` tutorial I'm not able to find out how to do that.
Doing this:

```
<random-directive [binded]='name' [binded2]='name2'></random-directive>
```

Leads to one way binding to name only. But I want to change the variable from directive itself so is it possible?

Comment: you can use ngModel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<random-directive [(ngModel)]='name'></random-directive>
```

In order to use `ngModel` you have to import in your module `FormsModule from "@angular/forms"`

Here is an example plunker I made for you:

https://plnkr.co/edit/AReq0QngbE9130Bd38Qq?p=preview

You can't use multiple variables with a single `ngModel`, but you can bind it to an object. If you define in your ts an object like this:

```
public myObject = { name: 'John', surname: 'Doe' }
```

Then you can bind multiple inputs to your object properties, like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myObject.name" />
<input [(ngModel)]="myObject.surname" />
```

According to your edit you need to use `@Input()`

In your .ts component declare `@Input() binded;` and `@Input() binded2;` at the beginning of you component.

```
export class RandomDirective {
   @Input() binded;
   @Input() binded2;
}
```

then you can use

```
<random-directive [(binded)]=“myVar” [(binded2)]=“myVar2”><random-directive>
```

Comment: Can you use multiple variables with [(ngModel)]  ?

Comment: I've edited the question @Gianluca Paris Can please edit your answer accordingly as I think I'm not able to explain what I want so I created a plunk for that.

Comment: And how to use @Input() or @Output please edit your plunk I'm stuck here for long time now

Comment: done, please also check documentation https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1):

### Two way binding

**Angular 1**

```
 <input ng-model="username">
```

**Angular2 and all above versions**

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="username">
```

### One way binding for all versions

```
<p>Hello {{username}}!</p>
```

You could check this [documentation of two way binding in angular:](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) for more information.

Comment: Can you use multiple variables with [(ngModel)] ?

Comment: @BlackMamba No, as per my knowledge you can't, reason is you can bind single variable at the time of binding , but yes you can use method too.

Comment: @PardeepJain In angular Js we used to use ng-model for inputs only and like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs questioni

Comment: @BlackMamba, yes I know. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Can you please provide a way as requested in my updated question

Answer (score 0):

[This blog helped me a lot](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html):

**One thing that both the above answers not specifying was the valueChange that is to be emitted so that the value change reflects automatically.That was what confusing me.**

```
//If using ngModel this is the html
<input [ngModel]="username" (ngModelChange)="username = $event">
// Or go with [(ngModel)]
<p>Hello {{username}}!</p>
//The component here
@Component({

 selector: 'custom-counter',
  template: `
    <button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
    <span>{{counter}}</span>
    <button (click)="increment()">+</button>
  `
})
export class CustomCounterComponent {

  counterValue = 0;

  get counter() {
    return this.counterValue;
  }

  set counter(value) {
    this.counterValue = value;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++'
  }
}


// The parent here
@Component()
export class CustomCounterComponent {

  counterValue = 0;

  @Input()
  get counter() {
       return this.counterValue;
     }
      ...
  }
  //The html
<custom-counter [(counter)]="someValue"></custom-counter>

<p>counterValue = {{someValue}}</p>
//The directive with model config
@Component()
export class CustomCounterComponent {

  ...
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();

  set counter(val) {
    this.counterValue = val;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }
  ...
}
```