# What does binding means? and what is this symbols?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to use hypothesis annotation locally and I want to change some function. So I want to know what does these "<", "&" symbols means?

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    icon: '<',
    isDisabled: '<',
    label: '<',
    onClick: '&',
  },
  template: require('../templates/annotation-action-button.html'),
};
```

Comment: Incorrect tag should be angularjs.
Link which may help you: 
http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/dissecting-bindings-in-angularjs/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between & vs @ and = in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908133/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-and-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These symbols define data binding strategies for an AngularJS directive or component.

- `<` symbol denotes one-way (parent ⇒ child) binding. It means that changes made to the passed value that happen in the parent scope are reflected in the child scope but not vice versa. Two-way (parent ⇔ child) binding strategy is denoted by `=` symbol.
- `&` symbol denotes parent execution binding. It provides a possibility to invoke a function in the context of parent scope. Typically it's used to pass a reference to a method defined in the parent scope to a child.

Official documentation for data binding strategies in components can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).