# Problems with local scope properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want declare directive in DOM and set scope properties like a Local scope property and can't do it...

If I have property type int, its fine but if dateType is string or datetime I have troubles...

This is my html declare:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <time-reminding relative-days-to-finish="10" reminder-name="Robo"></time-reminding>
</div>
```

and here is directive:

```
myApp.directive('timeReminding', function() {
    return {
        template: "<div>foo - {{relativeDaysToFinish}}<br />{{reminderName}}</div>",
        scope: {
            relativeDaysToFinish: '=',
            reminderName: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: "E",
        constroller: function($scope){

        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DavidSlavik/rj3Rr/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: You have "Unexpected token )" error in your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this: `reminder-name="foo"` or this: `reminder-name="'Robo'"` 
for two-way binding (`=`) . Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rj3Rr/9/

And like this:

```
 reminder-name="{{foo}}"
```

for a one-way (`@`) , http://jsfiddle.net/rj3Rr/6/

Great Mark Rajcok's explanation: [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope/14063373#14063373)

Comment: And why it stops working when I use "@" instead of "=" in scope declaration?

Comment: @DavidSlavík Have a look at Mark Rajcok's explanations and related links that he gives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope/14063373#14063373