# Passing an object to a directive as an argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-directive

I have a view and a controller for it:

```
<app-head options="options"></app-head>

app.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.options = {
    first: {
        description: "A link",
        link: "../"
    },
    second:{
        description: "Another link",
        link: "../../"
    }
  };
});
```

I want to use the object `options` within my directive:

```
app.directive('appHead',function(){

  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/modules/appHead.html',
    replace: true,
    controller: function($scope,$element,$attrs){
      $scope.options = $attrs.options;
    }
  }
});
```

When i call `console.log($scope.options)` in my directive's controller however, it will return `options
No Properties`

Why is that and how do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
app.directive('appHead',function(){
    return{
        scope: { 
            options: '=', 
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/modules/appHead.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope,$element,$attrs){
            // $scope.options 
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CfKZJ1QtmYNRCT141ffN?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. JHowever, this gives me the exact same result as before. Nevertheless, what is that '=' supoosed to do? And how would i accomplish that without switching to an isolate scope?

Comment: @user2422960, Now You will get value in `$scope.options` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

Comment: Unfortunately, i ain't. The object has still no properties

Comment: it is still not working. Thanks for your efforts anyways. I believe that the issue lays in the fact that the object is created inside of another controller

Comment: @user2422960, see demo its working, you can see console is populated. You must have error in somewhere else