# Data from directive not displaying within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have broken this problem down into it's simplest form. Basically I have a directive that, for the demo, doesn't yet really do anything. I have a div with the directive as an attribute. The values within the div, which come from an object array, are not displayed. If I remove the directive from the div, they are displayed OK. I am clearly missing something really obvious here as I have done this before without any problems.

Here's the Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZUXD4qW5hXvB7y9RG6sB?p=preview

Script:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.tooltips = [{"id":1,"warn":true},{"id":2,"warn":false},{"id":3,"warn":true},{"id":4,"warn":true}];

});

app.directive("cmTooltip", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            cmTooltip: "="
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="tip in tooltips" class="titlecell" cm-tooltip="true">
    A div element: {{ tip.id }}
</div>
<br><br>

Just to prove it works without the directive:
<div ng-repeat="tip in tooltips" class="titlecell">
    A div element: {{ tip.id }}
</div>
```

Comment: Just changing your angular version to the latest (1.2.5) makes your plunk work: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js

Comment: Would love to do that but I have 8000 lines of code that would all need updating - not too keen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *hack* to make it working in earlier versions of angular by making use of `transclusion`, like that:

```
app.directive("cmTooltip", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
           cmTooltip: "="
        },
        transclude:  true,
        template : '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

<kbd>[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/lorjqCVqnZIJQCjn2ZQe?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

*As by Beyers' comment above and below, the behaviour the question is about no longer exists in at least 1.2.5*

To be clearer; this has *nothing to do with ng-repeat*, you can remove it and there still will be no `tip` ( or `tooltips` ).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) question on what the `=` and other configs mean and what it is doing for you.

Basically for your situation when you use `=` the scope of the directive will be used in the underlying elements, you no longer have your controller's scope. What this means for you is that there is no `{{ tip.id }}` or not even `tip`. Because the directive doesn't supply one.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QHiD5sQA42n7amKe4jaO?p=preview) that demonstrates what you can do with it.

Basically all i did was

```
app.directive("cmTooltip", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            cmTooltip: "="
        },
        link: function($scope){    // <<
          $scope.tip = { id: 1 };  // <<
        }                          // <<
    };
});
```

This creates the tip object on the scope so it has an id.

For your situation you would probably just not use `=` and look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) question for your other options depending on what you want.

Comment: See my comment above, just changing the original plunk to use latest (1.2.5) angular version makes it work. So I suspect there's been some bug fixes in latest versions in regards to multiple directives and isolated scopes.

Comment: Thanks, i thought i'd tried that too by changing the `data-require="angular.js@1.0.x"` I was thinking I'd already checked it, there have been many breaking changes from 1.0 to 1.2 so ill add that.

Comment: Thanks Philipp, this has really helped my understanding of isolate scopes.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion this isn't the way to go.
I would use Objects.

JS code:

```
  function tooltip(id,warn){
    this.id = id;
    this.warn = warn;
  }

  tooltip.prototype.toString = function toolToString(){
    return "I'm a tooltip, my id = "+this.id+" and my warn value = "+this.warn;
  }

  $scope.tooltips = [new tooltip(1,true),new tooltip(2,false),new tooltip(3,true),new tooltip(4,true)];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="tip in tooltips" class="titlecell">
        A div element: {{ tip.toString() }}
    </div>
```

Comment: The OP knows how to make this work, by removing his directive, the question is about why it doesn't work when he applies the directive. This is not what the question is about, and you're basically even putting view logic into the JS. wtf?

Comment: I agree - thanks for the answer but it has nothing to do with my question.