# setting ng-disabled in a directive from outer controller $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The linked fiddle contains a simple directive with a `<select>`. I would like to disable the `<select>` tag by setting a variable in the outer controller. In devtools I see the value of ng-disabled to change from `false` to `true`, but the `<select>` remains enabled. Could someone help me on what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/bika/PRsH7/12/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
.directive( 'myTag', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            isDisabled: '=' //use 2-way binding instead.
        },
        template: '<select ng-disabled="isDisabled"><option>not disabled</option></select>'
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<my-tag is-disabled="isDisabled"></my-tag>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CAF7F/)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when using "@", isDisabled is evaluated at a string, not a boolean. isDisabled is an expression, and hence you should use "&" to pass it to your directive.

```
    .directive( 'myTag', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          isDisabled: '&'
        },
        template: '<select ng-disabled="isDisabled()"><option>not disabled</option></select>',
      };
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bulbul/PRsH7/16/

More reference: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/
[What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

You might also want to watch John Lindquist's awesome videos on directives: https://egghead.io/search?q=directive