# Passing data to a custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page that displays a bunch of thumbnails of images that are retrieved using http. I use ng-repeat to go through the array and generate the html.
This works fine.

I also create a custom directive that I tie as an attribute to img elements generated by ng-repeat.
This also works fine.

However, when I try to pass data to the scope of my custom directive then it all falls apart. Data binding fails, ng-repeat does not replace the url of the images so I end up getting a 404 since the url is invalid. That is pretty much as far as it goes.

Any help is greatly appreciated since I am completely new to Angular.

my html template:

```
<div class="portfolioContent">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-padding" ng-repeat="gImg in gPhotos">
        <div class="photoframe">
                <img src="{{gImg.thumbnailUrl}}" url="{{gImg.imageUrl}}" image-gallery>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my custom directive:

```
myApp.directive('imageGallery',function(){

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      url: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
        console.log($scope.url);
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
scope: {
  url: '='
},
```

to

```
scope: {
  url: '@'
},
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X58tu/1/) for a very simple example. Check the console. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) what the difference is between `=` and `@`.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify scope: { url:'=' }, you are specifying two-way model binding. The attribute passed as 'url' should be a model, not an interpolated string.

Try this:

```
<img ng-src="gImg.thumbnailUrl" url="gImg.imageUrl" image-gallery>
```

Comment: Your answer was also useful in helping me understand the the two way binding relationship, however since I don't want/need to update the value of gImg.thumbnailUrl in my directive this won't work. 
After Angular compiles this I end up with:
 
    `<img ng-src="gImg.thumbnailUrl" url="gImg.imageUrl" image-gallery="" class="ng-isolate-scope" src="gImg.thumbnailUrl">`

Comment: Since it is bound to a model, it should work. Likely, there is something else going on. But if attribute binding works, that's good to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to isolate scope anyway ?

Try this :

```
        myApp.directive('imageGallery',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link : function(scope, element, attributes){
                   console.log(attributes.url);
                  // will log your URL as an attribute
                  // here you can bind an even to do your job , E.g. : click , mouseover
             }
        }
        });
```