# "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at colum 2" in custom directive when using scope @

Tags: javascript, angularjs, custom-directive

I'm getting a custom directive from some library who has implimented directive as below:

```
var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                size: '@',
                id: '@toggleId',
                ngModel: '=',
                isDisabled: '@',
                csChange: '&',
                csTrueValue: '@',
                csFalseValue: '@',
            },
            template: ".......",
        };
```

since it is using some attribute with scope @ as in isDisabled I'm providing template as below:

```
<xa-ya-za toggle-id='x{{ vm.x }}' is-disabled='{{vm.p.q}}' ng-model='vm.y' name='thresholdToggle' size='small' ng-click='vm.n($event)'></xa-ya-za>
```

as said here [Passing data to a custom directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357908/passing-data-to-a-custom-directive-in-angularjs)

But it throws error as following:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{vm.p.q}}] starting at [{vm.p.q}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bvm.selected.onlythreshold%7D%7D&p4=%7Bvm.selected.onlythreshold%7D%7D
    at a-third-party.min.js:1
    at AST.throwError (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.object (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.primary (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.unary (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.multiplicative (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.additive (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.relational (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.equality (a-third-party.min.js:1)
    at AST.logicalAND (a-third-party.min.js:1)
```

As which is maintained here [Having a hard time debugging error - Token '{' invalid key at column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357055/having-a-hard-time-debugging-error-token-invalid-key-at-column-2)

> So I'm confused **How I'll pass variable to my custom directives**

Comment: i think there should be quotes here: `is-disabled='{{vm.p.q}}'`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quotes in your html

```
<xa-ya-za toggle-id='x{{ vm.x }}' is-disabled={{vm.p.q}} ng-model='vm.y' name='thresholdToggle' size='small' ng-click='vm.n($event)'></xa-ya-za>
```

should be

```
<xa-ya-za toggle-id='x{{ vm.x }}' is-disabled='{{vm.p.q}}' ng-model='vm.y' name='thresholdToggle' size='small' ng-click='vm.n($event)'></xa-ya-za>
```

I recommend to use double-quotes instead of single-quotes.