# Passing attrs as $scope variables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive and I'm trying to get the Attrs and pass them to the $scope, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. More specifically I'm trying to set attributes in my template equal to what the name is set in my date-picker tag. I tried setting them as a variable, but obviously that didn't work.
Help and further clarification is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

HTML

```
<date-picker id="dateendPicker" name="date_end"></date-picker>
```

JS

```
App.directive('datePicker', function(){
  return {
  scope: {
          name : '@'
         },
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  template: '<div class="date"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{this_name}}" name="{{this_name}}" ng-model="event.{{this_name}}" required/><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div>',
  controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.this_name = this_name;
  }],
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    var this_name = attrs.name;
  }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how you've defined your directive scope:

```
  scope: {
      name : '@'
  }
```

name is already a variable on your scope. If you're not doing anything special with it on your controller\link functions, you can drop them entirely, and in your template reference it with {{name}}. Just note that if you're creating scope bindings with '@', then in your html you should pass your data as an angular expression, meaning:

```
name="{{date_end}}"
```

Comment: More generally, you can also inject $element and $attrs into your controller along with $scope, but you don't need to do that here.

Comment: I guess I didn't specify. I'm hoping to get the name attr to set the value of the attributes="{{this_name}}" in the template.

Comment: Then you can just change it to scope: {this_name : '@name'}, you can even remove the link and controller from your directive.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see from your snippet, you want to use `name` attribute as ng-model into directive. I think, you should consider using another type of isolated scope ([related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063373/1065780))

Here is my approach ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goliney/gdf9U/2/)):

```
app.directive('datePicker', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: '=name'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: 
            '<div class="date">' +
                '<div class="input-group">' +
                    '<input type="text" ' +
                            'class="form-control" ' +
                            'id="bad-idea-to-make-it-editable-id" ' +
                            'name="{{ name }}" ' +
                            'ng-model="name" ' +
                            'required/>' +
                    '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        }
    });
```

So now you can edit parent scope from directive. But if you dont want this kind of communication between scopes, use `@` scope, as @haimlit [has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460916/1065780).

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code snippet:
First you do not assign the assign the attrs to the `scope` but to a local variable, so it won't be available in the controller function.

You could try this:

```
App.directive('datePicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            name : '@'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<div class="date"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{this_name}}" name="{{this_name}}" ng-model="event.{{this_name}}" required/><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.this_name = this_name;
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.this_name = attrs.name;
        }
    }
});
```

I do not know if this really works since it is not recommended to use controller and link functions at the same time (taken from the [directive guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)):

> Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.

But according to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) the attrs are also available as `$attrs` to the controller function:

```
App.directive('datePicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            name : '@'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<div class="date"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{this_name}}" name="{{this_name}}" ng-model="event.{{this_name}}" required/><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs){
            $scope.this_name = $attrs.name;
        }]
    }
});
```

But you have already defined `name` in the isolate scope, so it should be availble as `scope.name` in the conroller or link function:

```
App.directive('datePicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            name : '@'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<div class="date"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{this_name}}" name="{{this_name}}" ng-model="event.{{this_name}}" required/><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            console.log(scope.name); // this is your name defined as attribute name="..." on the tag
        }
    }
});
```