# AngularJS - Why is my directive isolated scope variable is undefined?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7YUpQ1tEjnUaX01txFcK?p=preview

When I run this, templateUrl is undefined in the scope.  Why?

My assumption here is that it's trying to find a variable named template.html in the parent scope, but can't, so it's assigning it to undefined.  If so, how do I pass this in as a string instead of a scope variable?

Html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">  
   <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
      <test-directive ng-model="testModel" 
                      template-url="template.html">
      </test-directive>
   </div>
</body>
```

.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.testModel = {}
});

app.directive("testDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: "=ngModel",
            templateUrl: "="
        },
        template: "<div ng-include='templateUrl'></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(scope.templateUrl);  // <-- Shows as undefined
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just change the scope:

```
    scope: {
        templateUrl: "@"
    },
```

you'll get the output 'template.html'.

The key point is the difference between '=' and '@'. You can refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Comment: Directive API has been moved to $compile.[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile]

Comment: Excellent answer explaining the difference in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14063373/3123195

Answer (score 3):

I figured out my problem.  I need to use @ instead of =.

```
app.directive("testDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: "=ngModel",
            templateUrl: "@"
        },
        template: "<div ng-include='templateUrl'></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(scope.templateUrl);  // <-- Works perfectly
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When you will use equal sign (=) into directive, you have to define this property under the $scope, other wise it does not work, It will produce error '' . see the angular document [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign). whether you can try templateUrl: "=?" or under the $scope.

According to angular document

```
<!-- ERROR because `1+2=localValue` is an invalid statement -->
<my-directive bind="1+2">

<!-- ERROR because `myFn()=localValue` is an invalid statement -->
<my-directive bind="myFn()">

<!-- ERROR because attribute bind wasn't provided -->
<my-directive>
```

To resolve this error, always use path expressions with scope properties that are two-way data-bound:

```
<my-directive bind="some.property">
<my-directive bind="some[3]['property']">
```

your solution is here [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMa5fNTnrNwKA4MMc6FY?p=preview)