# Angularjs Directives And Scopes (get a string not an obj)

Tags: angularjs

Hi All i have a problem with my directive, i searched in the forum for any solution but i didn't found  anything good for me.

I have a directive, in my html inside a ng-repeat and looks like this

```
<custom-slide item="{{slides[$index]}}" pos='$index'  ></custom-slide>
```

I need to pass item this way beacause I need to watch if the value of this object changed in my main controller.

My directive scope is like this:

```
 return {
restrict: 'E',
link: linker,
scope:{
    item: '@item',
    pos: '=pos'
    //slide: '@slide',

}
```

my problem it if when i use scope.item  what i get is a string and not an objetc.

```
{type:0, isSelected:'slide' ,param1:'',param2:' ',param3:' '}
```

But i get this as string,it's any way to have this as an object, without need to parse

any advice!!? thank you very much!

EDIT

i need to have item as an object because in my linker i change de template of the directive and,in this template i have somethings like:

```
   <div>
   <div class="mainText">{{scope.item.param1}}</div>
   <div class="footer Text">{{scope.item.param2}}</div>
   </div>
```

so when `{{scope.item.param1 }}` is evaluated the value is undefined, because isn't an object

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the {{}} from the item attr:

```
<custom-slide item="slides[$index]" pos="$index"></custom-slide>
```

Comment: i'm still having a string, in this case my item = "slides[$index]" .. I need to operate with {{}} to have the value of the expresion, but get the value as an object not as a string

Comment: Hm... well, you can try to JSON.parse() the string back to a object, if i find the answer to why you're getting a string i will post it here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

Comment: Try using: "item: '=item'" instead of using "item: '@item'"

Comment: yes, thats an option but, because of my code inside the linker, I need to get the item directly as an obj! =(, the option =item didnt work with {{}}

Comment: i think using your link, my solution is:

"With @, you will need to use attr.$observe('title', function(value) { ... }) if you need to use the value in your link(ing) function"   

isn't it?

so in my code i use:

 scope.$watch('item', function(newValue) {
          
            }
        });

but newvalue is a string!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `=` if you are trying to bind an expression:

```
 return {
restrict: 'E',
link: linker,
scope:{
    item: '=',
    pos: '=pos'
    //slide: '@slide',

}
```

Then pass the expression in the attribute without the braces:

```
<custom-slide item="slides[$index]" pos="$index" ></custom-slide>
```

Comment: oki ,thats makes item be an obj but $watch doesn't work, i think maybe because scope.item is an internal variable of the directive and  don't update when slides[index] is updated in the controller

Comment: I think it should. Maybe you need to pass object equality checking. [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: mmm not for me, i understand the = as a way to copy the value inside the directive scope, so if it change outside , the scope does not know, and the "@" as a way to pass the reference! maybe i'm wrong, but with "=" when i update the controller $scope.slide, inside the directive this change is not visible

Comment: Use $watchCollection, from inside your directive.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a string because you are literally placing the JSON in to the DOM, which is a very bad idea and removes your ability to modify by reference.

Basically you cannot pass the JSON as an attribute, in fact there is no reason to. Here is a version of your directive that will only pass 'how' you get at the data from the scope and the use $parse to actually get that data.

HTML

```
<custom-slide item="slides[$index]}.item}" pos='$index'  ></custom-slide>
```

Directive

```
module.directive('customSlide', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var pos = attrs.pos;
            var item = $parse(attrs.item)(scope);
        }
    }
});
```