# Pass $ value to paypal directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm hoping to use paypal and angularJS, I came across an awesome angularjs directive for paypal

```
<paypal-button business="cs@me.com" language-code="en_US" currency-code="USD"
    item-name="socks" amount="{{dollarValue}}" ng-model="paypalButton"></paypal-button>
```

The problem I'm having here is the amount for the button is passed via scope

Say the user wants 10 socks, each sock is $5, the user enters "10", a back end script multiplies 10x5 and returns 50 as the number that should go in the amount=""

how to I pass $scope.amount to be the amount submitted on the paypal form?

I've tried to see if I can pass amount to the paypal directive, but I'm having trouble passing it to the directive.

```
angular.module('WCtrl', [])
.controller('WController',['$scope','$q','$http','$location','$interval','$firebase','$timeout','$stateParams','$routeParams', function($scope,$q,$http,$location,$interval,$firebase,$timeout,$stateParams,$routeParams) {
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

/$scope.calculate = function(){
    //console.log("reached")
    $scope.calculate = $scope.calc();
    $scope.calculate = $scope.calculate.then(function(amount){

    $http.post('public/views/calculate.php?a='+amount,$.param($scope.FormData))
        .success(function(response){
            if(!response.success){

                $("#message").attr('class','alert alert-danger text-center')
                $scope.message = response.message
            }else{


                    $scope.amount = response.amount

            }
        })

    })
}


}])

.directive('paypalButton',function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        amount:'='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){    
           element.text(scope.amount);    
        },  
      compile: function(element, attrs) {
        var languageCodes = [ // PayPal allowed language codes
          'en_US',
          'es_ES',
          'fr_FR',
          'it_IT',
          'de_DE'
        ];
        var currencyCodes = [ // PayPal allowed currency codes
          'AUD',
          'CAD',
          'CZK',
          'DKK',
          'EUR',
          'HKD',
          'HUF',
          'ILS',
          'JPY',
          'MXN',
          'NOK',
          'NZD',
          'PHP',
          'PLN',
          'GBP',
          'RUB',
          'SGD',
          'SEK',
          'CHF',
          'TWD',
          'THB',
          'USD'
        ];
        var buttonSizes = [ // PayPal allowed button sizes
          'SM', // small
          'LG' // large
        ];
        var name = this.name;
        function err(reason) {
          element.replaceWith('<span style="background-color:red; color:black; padding:.5em;">' + name + ': ' + reason + '</span>');
          console.log(element.context);
        }
        var action = attrs.action || 'https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr';
        var business = attrs.business;
        var languageCode = attrs.languageCode || 'en_US';
        var currencyCode = attrs.currencyCode || 'USD';
        var itemName = attrs.itemName;
        var amount = parseFloat(attrs.amount);
        var buttonSize = attrs.buttonSize || 'SM';
        var imgAlt = attrs.imgAlt || 'Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!';
        if (!business) { return err('business not specified!'); }
        if (!itemName) { return err('item name not specified!'); }
        if (!amount) { return err('amount not specified!'); }
        if (isNaN(amount)) { return err('amount is not a number!'); }
        if (languageCodes.indexOf(languageCode) < 0) { return err('unforeseen language code!'); }
        if (currencyCodes.indexOf(currencyCode) < 0) { return err('unforeseen currency code!'); }
        if (buttonSizes.indexOf(buttonSize) < 0) { return err('unforeseen button size!'); }
        var imgSrc = 'http://www.paypalobjects.com/' + languageCode + '/i/btn/btn_buynow_' + buttonSize + '.gif';
        var template =
          '<form name="_xclick" action="' + action + '" method="post">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' + business + '">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' + currencyCode + '">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' + itemName + '">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' + amount + '">' +
          '<input type="image" src="' + imgSrc + '" border="0" name="submit" alt="' + imgAlt + '">' +
          '</form>';
        //element.replaceWith(template);
        element.append(template);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `amount="{{amount}}"`?

Comment: tried that doesn't work

Comment: can you clarify on why `amount="{{amount}}"` doesn't work? does it pass the wrong value? does it pass nothing at all? does it throw an error?

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14050195/2845029),  try changing `amount:'='` to `amount: '@'`.  Otherwise, use the double braces in the attribute value (which you use in the directive depends on if you only need the string value, or need to setup 2-way data binding between directive and parent scope).

Answer (score 0):

I'm seen a lot of folks searching for a paypal and angularjs option... here's what I did to get it all working using the code from the help I got here [render <script> tag in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554652/render-script-tag-in-angularjs)

from the controller I broadcast the paypal amount

```
$scope.$broadcast("paypalAmount", $scope.dollarValue)
```

using the provided directive I listen for the broadcast and update the amount for the payment button

```
.directive('paypal', [function(){
return {
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, iAttrs) {

                $scope.$on(
                    "paypalAmount",
                    function handlePingEvent( event, dollarValue ) {

                        var scriptElem = angular.element(document.createElement('script'))
                        scriptElem.attr({src:'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR-PAYPAL-EMAIL','data-button':'buynow','data-name':'Arcade Tokens','data-amount':dollarValue,'data-currency':'USD','data-callback':'https://gamerholic.com/ipn/data.php' }) // set var appropriately
                        element.append(scriptElem)

                    }
                );

    }
};
}]);
```