# render <script> tag in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add paypal's pay button to my angularjs app,

```
$scope.paypal ='<script async="async" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=DJOEURGOJ97S"'+ 
              'data-button="buynow"'+
              'data-name="socks"'+
              'data-quantity="1"'+ 
              'data-amount="{{dollarValue}}"'+
              'data-currency="USD"'+ 
              'data-shipping="0"'+
              'data-tax="0"'+
              'data-callback="https://gamerhoic.com/ipn/data.php"'+
          '></script>';
```

It would be so awesome IF it was just that easy.

I've tried a number of suggestions including adding ng-santize and $sce.trustAsHtml;

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('<script></script>');
```

I read through [Binding data in Angular js in string added via $sce.trustAsHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129647/binding-data-in-angular-js-in-string-added-via-sce-trustashtml) thoroughly but it's a bit more complex than what I'm doing

using $sce.trustAtHtml nothing renders. If I add {{paypal}} I obviously get the $scope.paypal '' text displayed

```
     <div bind-unsafe-html="paypal">{{paypal}}</div>
```

Comment: you say you tried `$sce.trustAsHtml()`, but you don't mention what it did or didn't do.  looks like this should work, so what is your actual question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best approach will be create a directive, then from in the directive you can use `angular.element` (basically jQuery lite) to add the script to the directive element.  Following should work out well:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('paypal', [function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            dollarValue: '@'
        },
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            var script = '<script async="async" src="' + 
                'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/' + 
                'paypal-button.min.js?merchant=DJOEURGOJ97S"'+ 
                'data-button="buynow"'+
                'data-name="socks"'+
                'data-quantity="1"'+ 
                'data-amount="' + $scope.dollarValue + '"'+
                'data-currency="USD"'+ 
                'data-shipping="0"'+
                'data-tax="0"'+
                'data-callback="https://gamerhoic.com/ipn/data.php"'+
                '></script>';

            var scriptElem = angular.element(script)
            iElm.append(scriptElem)
            scriptElem.on('ready', ...)
        }
    };
}]);
```

Notice this directive has isolate scope, and it is assigning it's `dollarValue` scope property to the string value of the parent's (so you can re-use directive)

Then in your view html, use the new custom directive as an element or attribute, specifying the `dollarAmt`:

`<paypal dollarAmt="{{dollarAmt}}"></paypal>`

*or*

`<div paypal dollarAmt="{{dollarAmt}}"></div>`

You should see your script tag get appended to it. You could also replace the containing element in the directive (reassign `element` in `link` fn to whatever you want.)

Check out this [guide to creating custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), it's really cool

**UPDATE**

Looks like to create these script tags it's more foolproof to use `document.createElement()` rather than `angular.element` ([see here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/08/dynamically-injecting-script-tags-with-angularjs.aspx))

I changed the directive above to use this code and was able to see the paypal button appear on the page:

```
var scriptElem = angular.element(document.createElement('script'))
scriptElem.attr("src", scriptUrl) // set var appropriately
element.append(scriptElem)
```

Comment: holy crap it would be nice if stackoverflow allowed tipping in bitcoin... it's still not rendering but by far it's the best I've gotten from hours of searching

Comment: It is a good answer, however I would do a +1 when the dollarValue is coming from the directive scope and make it isolated directive so that it can be reused.

Comment: good catch, I just cut & pasted, I guess you would probably want more data attributes coming from the parent scope as well

Comment: fiddle please someone can't get this to work.
I'm reading the angularjs directives book, love angular but LOTS of work arounds.

I'm trying this way now because I couldn't pass the dollarValue from the parent to the directive before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533075/pass-value-to-paypal-directive-angularjs

this has been a two day battle

Answer (score 2):

I'm seen a lot of folks searching for a paypal and angularjs option... here's what I did to get it all working using the code from the awesome help I got above

from the controller I broadcast the paypal amount

```
$scope.$broadcast("paypalAmount", $scope.dollarValue)
```

using the provided directive I listen for the broadcast and update the amount for the payment button

```
.directive('paypal', [function(){
return {
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, iAttrs) {

                $scope.$on(
                    "paypalAmount",
                    function handlePingEvent( event, dollarValue ) {

                        var scriptElem = angular.element(document.createElement('script'))
                        scriptElem.attr({src:'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR-PAYPAL-EMAIL','data-button':'buynow','data-name':'Arcade Tokens','data-amount':dollarValue,'data-currency':'USD','data-callback':'https://gamerholic.com/ipn/data.php' }) // set var appropriately
                        element.append(scriptElem)

                    }
                );

    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a module to overcome this problem. 
Please take a look at: https://github.com/umair321/Inpage-js-render-for-angularjs

Very much easy to use:

Install it using bower: `bower install inpage-js-render-angular1`

Just include js-render.js to your page

Add 'ngLoadScript' to your app dependencies. E.g. angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME', ['ngLoadScript'])

Used it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript-inpage"> 
  /**Your Script here**/ 
</script>
```