# Adding <script> tag to angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this script tag that I want to add into my angular project:

```
<script>
 var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

 var x = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
   .range([0, 420]);

 d3.select(".chart")
   .selectAll("div")
     .data(data)
   .enter().append("div")
     .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
  </script>
```

I've been trying to figure out what the best way to add this snippet into my angularjs app.  I saw this here: [render <script> tag in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554652/render-script-tag-in-angularjs) but this question was asked a while ago, so I wanted to see if there was a better (newer) way to accomplish this.  I initially added it to my view but i'm not able to pass any data from my controller into the  block.  For example, I wanna do something like:

```
 var data = {{someArray}};
```

But i end up getting an error:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to this.  Would it be best to just follow the example in the link above? Let me know what you all think, thanks!

Comment: This is not correct. refer to this article. this might help you. http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-charting-directives-using-angularjs-d3-js/

Comment: You can't do that, use a directive

Comment: Thanks @micronyks that's exactly what I needed.