# Integrating Buy It Now button with Angular website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal, angularjs-scope, backand

I am trying to set up a simple app that:

1. Allows a user to buy and item through Buy It Now button.
2. Pay for the item view Paypal
3. On successful payment, return back to my site and insert the data (username, address in to an online DB).. Im using Backand.

I can get the Buy It Now button to display:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="herschelgomez@xyzzyu.com">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12oz Bottle">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" ng-value="username">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

But my user enters their data like:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/>
```

How can i bind the value entered above, to be inserted in to the hidden `input` type in my Buy It Now form.

I have tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" ng-value="username">
```

However this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554652/render-script-tag-in-angularjs

Comment: @K.Toress - thanks, provides a decent insight, but doesnt actually work.

Comment: Solved it using: <input type="hidden" name="amount" value={{amount}}>

Comment: Hi can  you mark this as resolve? just paste your answer and mark resoved