# Does anyone know why my AngularJS directives do not display as expected?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Update: See Jim Schubert's answer for the fix.  See [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) for why this matters.

I have three ways to display dynamic text in an AngularJS directive and they are all giving me different issues.  I would like to pass in a value via an attribute that will display in my template.  My template is actually a file but I converted [this simplified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh9qwo1L/5/) to use template show my issue.

You can see in the code below or in the JSFiddle that I have 3 examples.

1. Repeat use of the first example will only show the last use for every use on the page.  This allows for spaces, underscores, ect.
2. This allows for repeat use on the page, but does not allow for spaces, underscores, ect.
3. This allows for both repeat use and spaces, underscores, ect.  The issue with this is I do not expect the object to be the same for every use of the directive.  I.E.  I want to pass in the text and value from any object, text could be text={{ruhOh}} or text={{iLikePeanutButter}}.  I could map it, but that is additional overhead.

**What I expect**
Allow repeat use of directives with dynamic text and different text on each directive.  Allow underscores, spaces, ect.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <!--Always displays the last use for every use-->
    <ntt-form-text text="OperationsA" value="3"></ntt-form-text>
    <ntt-form-text text="OperationsB" value="3"></ntt-form-text>

    <!--three will display here-->
    <ntt-form-text-three text="Operations" value="5" obj="obj"></ntt-form-text-three>

    <!--spaces, underscores, dashes, ect cause display errors, tried both single and double quotes-->
    <ntt-form-text-two text="Operations A" value="5"></ntt-form-text-two> <!-- displays {{text}} -->
    <!--<ntt-form-text-two text="Description_2" value="5"></ntt-form-text-two>--> <!-- displays blank -->
    <!--<ntt-form-text-two text="ASDF-2" value="5"></ntt-form-text-two>--> <!-- displays -2 -->

    <!--three will fail to display here due to failure in two-->
    <ntt-form-text-three text="description" value="6" obj="obj"></ntt-form-text-three>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('nttFormText', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            //scope: false,
            template: '<div>Text: {{text}}</div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.text = attrs.text;
                scope.value = attrs.value;
            }
        };
    }])

myApp.directive('nttFormTextTwo', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { text: '=', value: '=' },
            template: '<div>Text: {{text}}</div>'
        };
    }])

myApp.directive('nttFormTextThree', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { text: '=', value: '=', obj: '=' },
            template: '<div>Text: {{text}} Value: {{value}} Spaced Word: {{obj.spacedWord}}</div>'
        };
    }])

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = { spacedWord: "hello world!" };
});
```

Comment: Post the code here. Show us an example of directive usage. Tell us what you expect the directive to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: All code is in JSFiddle.  The JS was displaying funny in SO so I took it out.

Comment: Added JS, wrapped it in code, see how bad it looks.  See comments in HTML for what it displays, what I expect is for it to not to repeat, to allow spaces, underscores, ect.

Comment: It looks bad because you didn't include it correctly. It's quite simple: you copy paste the code, select it, and hit Ctrl-K (or press the "code" button in the toolbar, which looks like '{}')

Comment: I did use Ctrl-K, thank you, next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gh9qwo1L/7/

I think the problem you're having is using scope bindings. From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive:

- To bind to the attribute in `<div bind-to-this="thing">`, you'd specify a binding of `=bindToThis`
- use `&attr` in the scope option when you want your directive to expose an API for binding to behaviors.

The missing binding from the documentation is `@`, which will bind to a value.  I've updated your fiddle to make one of your directives work as you're expecting. For example:

```
myApp.directive('nttFormTextThree', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            // NOTE: '=' means two way binding, '@' means bind to a value.
            scope: { text: '@', value: '=', obj: '=' },
            template: '<div>Text: {{text}} Value: {{value}} Spaced Word: {{obj.spacedWord}}</div>'
        };
    }])

   // usage
   <ntt-form-text-three text="Operations" value="5" obj="obj"></ntt-form-text-three>
```

The `@` allows you to bind text to be displayed as text.

Here's how you'd use it the way you had it (`text: '='`):

```
myApp.directive('nttFormTextThreeEx', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { text: '=', value: '=', obj: '=' },
            template: '<div>Text: {{text}} Value: {{value}} Spaced Word: {{obj.spacedWord}}</div>'
        };
    }])

// in your parent scope:
$scope.operations = 'Operations on scope';

// template usage bound to scope
<ntt-form-text-three-ex text="operations" value="5" obj="obj"></ntt-form-text-three-ex>

// template usage bound to text
<ntt-form-text-three-ex text="'Wrapped in quotes'" value="5" obj="obj"></ntt-form-text-three-ex>
```

Comment: The '@' vs '=' was what did the trick.  It is always one character lol.