# Why the form does not get updated while the $scope does AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

So I am having a form and when I load the form I call a function with it. The function fills the form with some data.

```
$scope.fill = function {

                            $scope.formData.name = 'Sara';
                            console.log($scope.formData.name);

                        })
```

And on the index view I have the following:

```
<div class="form-group">                
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="formData.name"></div>
```

So when I press the the button :

```
<button ng-controller="formController" ui-sref="front.form.profile" ng-click="fill()">Fill</button>
```

I want the form  about the name to be filled with the value I defined.

The problem I have is that the $scope is updated, on console.log I get the name sara but the form is still empty and does not get updated>

I added $scope.apply() in the end of the function but it does not make any change .
Please help

Comment: Don't you get any console error? And please close the input tag

Comment: No I dont get any error

Answer (score 3):

ng-controller="formController" ui-sref="front.form.profile" ng-click="fill()"

Also you created children controller, also $scope is child scope, so that if you change value of child scope, the value of "$scope.formData.name" of parent's scope not changing.

you can using two-way binding via directive. 
references: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

I hope that is helpful for you!

Comment: I will check it out tmr, Thank you for your response

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by  two-way binding via directive. Thank you

Comment: you can read it at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

Answer (score 2):

Your button has its own controller:

```
<button ng-controller="formController"
```

That creates a child scope for the button only. Remove it. You should also create the ui-sref attribute, since you wan't the button to fill the form, not to navigate to another state.

Comment: but the form is in another state. So I navigate to the state where the form is and then update it

Comment: The button is in the front page, and the form is in the front.form.profile so I navigate there and call the function

Comment: The controller in the button is the controller  where my function lies. Should I delete it ?

Comment: That's not at all what your code does. What it does is creating a **new** scope for the button and create a **new** instance of the formController with this new scope. If your goal is to navigate to a different state, then use the ui-sref directive, and pass parameters.

Comment: I want to navigate to a different state and call the function to populate my view .

Comment: I actually pass to the new state but the form does not get populated while the scope contains the value. What do you mean by  "use ui-sref directive, and pass parameter" ?