# Angularjs - url params: When clicked returns to angular vars in the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-click="go('pair/{{message.currencyFrom}}/{{message.currencyTo}}')">
      <td>{{ message.currencyFrom }}/{{ message.currencyTo }}</td>
      <td>{{ message.amountSell }}</td>
      <td>{{ message.amountBuy }}</td>
      <td>{{ message.rate }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

The dom view in chrome's inspect, shows `ng-click="go('pair/EUR/GBP')"` however when clicked I end up at `pair/%7B%7Bmessage.currencyFrom%7D%7D/%7B%7Bmessage.currencyTo%7D%7D`

It seems the the url is passed as raw angular vars.

I've tried adding the code inside the loop but the same behaviour is exhibited.
I've tried initiating a variable first and passing it to the `go` function:
`ng-init="var url = 'pair/{{message.currencyFrom}}/{{message.currencyTo}}'"`

I can't imagine it's relevant but here is go:

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
        $location.path( path );
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
ng-click="go('pair/' + message.currencyFrom + '/' + message.currencyTo)"
```

It's because you write expression inside `ng-click`, not template. Same with `ng-init`.

**In directive:**

```
scope: {
    foo: '=', // This means `foo` must be an expression
    bar: '@' // This means `bar` must be template
}
```

[See this question for detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

Comment: Sigh.. I tried this but wrapped the vars {{}}.. ah well. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The '{{}}' will be evaluated as characters, not as valid Angular code. Change it to:

```
go('pair/' + message.currencyFrom + '/' + message.currencyTo);
```

Angular will handle everything between quotes in a ng-click as Javascript code, so no need to use '{{' or '}}'.