# Can I use '=' instead of '&' in directive isolate scope?

Tags: angularjs

when I use '=' to pass a function, it works fine.
But why the '&' exsits? Is it just let it look like an event?

Comment: `&` invokes an expression; `=` is bi-directional binding

Comment: `&` is for passing functions (it is actually an expression but you can imagine it as a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Attribute's interpolation: `@`

`@` indicates to AngularJS that should interpolate the value of the specified attribute (the value in the isolated scope changes if the attribute's value changes).

## Binding data to the attribute: `=`

`=` indicates to AngularJS that should keep the expression of the specified attribute (the value in the isolated scope changes if the attribute's expression changes).

## Providing a callback: `&`

`&` indicates to AngularJS that the expression specified in the attribute will be avaliable on the isolated scope as a function that will execute the expression. Use this option to create **callbacks**.

http://codepen.io/ces/pen/ZGOLOq

Comment: Is there any time we can't use '=' but can use '&'

Comment: I think no. But if you need to use variables from parent scope is simpler passing only a callback function (using `&`) that passing the function and all the variables that you need to directive (using `=`). http://codepen.io/ces/pen/xGOLdg

Comment: You have more examples and information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope