# Directive cannot replace variable in template: Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive

I created a directive which has a directive inside it, and when I try to give it parameters I get this message: [This error message](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7BchartConfig%7D%7D&p4=%7BchartConfig%7D%7D)

Here is my directive

```
app.directive('percentageSquare', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            color: '@',
            chartConfig: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/charts/PercentageChart.html'
    };
});
```

Which loads this template:

```
<div class="drop-shadow">
    <highchart id="{{chartConfig}}" config="{{chartConfig}}" style="background-color: {{color}};" ng-show="true"></highchart>
</div>
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
<percentage-square color="yellow" chart-config="chartBounceRate"></percentage-square>
```

I am not sure what I can do to fix it, because it look just fine to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way [**highcharts**](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) works, it want to have config to be an object from scope. so you should use two way binding here

**Directive**

```
scope: {
   color: '@',
   chartConfig: '=', //<--two way binding here
   selector: '@'
},
```

**Directive Use**

```
<percentage-square color="'yellow'" chart-config="chartBounceRate" selector="{{selector}}"></percentage-square>
```

**Template**

```
<div class="drop-shadow">
    <highchart id="{{selector}}" config="chartConfig" 
       ng-style="{background-color: color}" ng-show="true">
    </highchart>
</div>
```

## EDIT

See [this famous stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14050195/3197383) to understand `@`, `&` and `=` in angularjs directive definition

Comment: That works! Do you have a link to the description of those binding types? I don't see them on the angular directives page here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn its basically related to https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng this directive API implementation..

Comment: I mean for the different types of bindings, such as `@`, `=`, `&` I don't know what any of those mean and it isn't in the documentation link above.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, you can see this popular question and answer on sof to know more about &, = and @ : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14050195/3197383