# check value of isolated scope variable in link function - directives in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following html:

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="protocolCtrl as pctrl">

    <!--IN THIS MODAL YOU CAN ADD/CHANGE/DELETE DATA-->

    <modal-directive list="pctrl" headers="['ID', 'Protocol']"></modal-directive>

</div>
```

In my `modal-directive.html`, in the body, I do this:

```
<!-- Modal body-->

<div class="modal-body">

    <table-directive list=list headers=headers></table-directive>

</div>
```

I want to check on the `list` parameter i pass in. if it's equal some value, I want to append some html to the body

My directive looks like this

```
.directive('modalDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/directives/modal-directive.html',
        scope: {
            list: '=',
            headers: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            if(scope.list == 'pctrl'){
                element.find('.modal-body').append('This is just a test.')
            }
        }
    };
});
```

But this doesn't append anything. If I drop the `if` check it appends just fine.

I'm fairly new to angular, so if anyone can tell me how I can achieve this, I'd appreciated it.

**Edit**

this is how i loop through the data in my `table-directive.html`

```
 <tr ng-repeat="l in list.list">

     <!--Access the actual values inside each of the objects in the array-->

     <td ng-repeat="data in l"> {{ data }} </td>

     <td>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                 data-toggle="modal">Edit</button>
     </td>

     <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="list.removeData(l)"
                    data-dismiss="modal">Remove</button>
     </td>

 </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put

```
<modal-directive list="pctrl" headers="['ID', 'Protocol']"></modal-directive>
```

and

```
....
  scope: {
        list: '=',
        headers: '='
    },
.....
```

`list: '='` check for the `list` attr of the element and execute the argument as a **expression not as a string** i think your trying to get `'pctrl'` as a string not as a scope variable value so that change to `list="'pctrl'"` to pass as a string

```
<modal-directive list="'pctrl'" headers="['ID', 'Protocol']"></modal-directive>
```

**OR**

get the attr as a string use `@`

```
....
  scope: {
        list: '@',
        headers: '='
    },
.....
```

here is a good [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope).

here is the angular official [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

**update**

if you need to check only the string value of the attr, then you can simply use `attrs.list`

so use it inside the directive as

```
if(attrs.list === 'pctrl'){
    element.find('.modal-body').append('This is just a test.')
}
```

Comment: hm, that made the if check work. But now it won't display any data in my table-directive. I'm using the `pctrl` to loop through an array as well. So it it possible to just check the equality of the object itself or something?

Comment: how do you do it in `table-directive` ?

Comment: do you have something `$scope.list` in the controller ?

Comment: ah - awesome! And now I can the `=` instead of `@` yes?

Comment: last question if you don't mind - If I want to append on another directive - is there something else that I need to in order to make that work?

Comment: glad to help you, but one point, angular directives are reusable, so you can use this directive multiple times in your app, so may be this  `<modal-directive list="pctrl" headers="['ID', 'Protocol']"></modal-directive>` code lays in different controllers so in all the controllers you have to use `list="pctrl"` and there should be a exact the same variable name as `$scope.pctrl` because your considering the variable name as `attrs.list` so its leading to a bad practice, if you can declare a another attr to detect `pctrl` or not it would be better just a suggestion, may be your case is different

Comment: umm im not clear about what u asked can you please describe it a bit :) `If I want to append on another directive`?

Comment: the modal-directive is suppsoed to able to work with multiple different controllers, so I think this is pretty reusable :) Reagarding my last question - never mind, I figures it out :)