# Why does @ bind this AngularJS attribute but = does not?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Why `color: "@"` work but `color: "="` not work in the below code?

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pz2L6etv/8/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function mainController($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'alsjkf';
}

myApp.directive('uiCalendar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            message: "@theMessage",
            color: "=" //works with @
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.color = scope.color === undefined ? 'black' : scope.color;
            $(element).append('<p style="color:'+scope.color+'">added this2: ' + scope.message + ' (' + scope.color + ')</p>');
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `=` is used to bind to variable in parent scope contained within the attribute value

Your color values are not scope variables in the parent scope(controller), they are only strings in your use case. There is no `$scope.green` or `$scope.blue` in controller to bind to.

The `=` would work if you did:

```
function mainController($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'alsjkf';
    $scope.blue ='#0B0EFF';
}
```

Then the hex value would be used inside scope of directive.

`@` will just take the string value and pass it to directive scope

Comment: Great, thanks, I got this working where the directive changes the values in the parent scope, if anyone is looking for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pz2L6etv/14/

Answer (score 0):

Directive bindings have different approaches to how they are interpreted.

Using `@` means that the scope variable is bound to the string literal value that is passed as that attribute. So using `color: '@'` binds the scope variable `color` to the exact value of `color="green"`, which would be `scope.color == "green" // this evaluates to true`

Using `=` binds the scope variable to the evaluation of the expression passed in the attribute. You can use string expressions to get literals, like `color: "="` and then have `<span color="'green'"></span>`

Using `&` binds the scope variable to the function that is passed in the attribute. Doing something like `click: '&'` and then `<span click="clickMe()"></span>` will make `scope.click()` fire off `clickMe()`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) has some more info and links to other resources that go into more detail.