# How to call $scope method from containing Controller, from inside a Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a partial that I construct like this

```
<my-partial attr1="some text" attr2="some other text">
   <div ng-show="displayBool">
      <div>{{attr1}}</div>
      <div>{{attr2}}</div>
      <button ng-click="changeBool()">Change var</button>
</my-partial>
```

which renders

```
   <div>some text</div>
   <div>some other text</div>
```

In the controller I set `$scope.displayBool = true`. And the directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('grasshopperApp')
    .directive('myPartial', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                displayBool: '=',
                attr1: '@'
                attr2: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: '../my.html'
        };
    });
```

`displayBool` does not come through in the directive and the div is never shown, yet the attribute values display correctly when I inspect the hidden element in the developer panel. Why is this? How can I make that value come through?

Comment: Related question with some great answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a **controller** to your directive, and set some properties.

So you can do :

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function directive() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            attr1: '@',
            attr2: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        //Declare controller for our custom directive
        controller: function($scope){
          //Set displayBool property
          $scope.displayBool = true;
        }
    };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('myPartial', directive);

})();
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-show="displayBool">
   <div>{{attr1}}</div>
   <div>{{attr2}}</div>
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<my-partial attr1="some text" attr2="some other text"><my-partial>
```

You can see [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BsN5kiSX5kuHwnvBOztf?p=preview)

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to putting the controller in the directive?

Comment: No, the controller is defined within the context of the directive, so you can simplify your code. Moreover it can be injected into other directives in order to facilitate communication between directive. In other word, it's useful :)

Comment: Awesome knowledge! How would you share it between directives? That sounds really cool.

Comment: I've made an example, with master and slave directive. You can see the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2lPryqaulLwSeb075OO?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion in the comments and OP's updated code, here's a potential solution. `displayBool` is brought in to the directive's isolate scope using 2-way binding. We also reference the controller's $scope method `changeBool` using the `&` modifier.

**Directive**

```
angular.module('grasshopperApp')
    .directive('myPartial', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                attr1: '@',
                attr2: '@',
                changeBool: '&',
                displayBool: '='
            },
            templateUrl: '../my.html'
        };
    });
```

**Template**

```
 <div ng-show="displayBool">
     <div>{{attr1}}</div>
     <div>{{attr2}}</div>
     <button ng-click="changeBool()">Change var</button>
 </div>
```

`displayBool` and `changeBool()` here both refer to the *directive's* isolate scope.

Assuming a controller `MyController` exists, similar to:

```
angular.module('grasshopperApp')
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.displayBool = true;
        $scope.changeBool = function() {
            $scope.displayBool = !$scope.displayBool;  
        }  
     }]);
```

You might use this directive like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <my-partial 
        attr1="some text"
        attr2="some other text" 
        display-bool=displayBool
        change-bool="changeBool()">
    </my-partial>
</div>
```

Here `display-bool` is bound to `MyController's` $scope variable `displayBool`   and `change-bool` is bound to `MyController's` $scope function `changeBool`, called, as a string.

I took this largely from the [Angular dev guide on directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) from the section that starts:

> Next, we want to add buttons to this dialog box, and allow someone using the directive to bind their own behavior to it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this really detailed solution. Can you explain what the difference is between `angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl, ....` and and adding a controller method to the directive return?

Comment: I'm certainly no angular expert; I look at the difference as largely organizational. I use module-level controllers for "bigger" parts of the app - a piece of UI that may contain *multiple* directives and other behaviors. I use directive controllers when I just need a little logic - usually show/hide type stuff - for the directive to function. There is probably a more technical difference but it hasn't mattered much in my (limited) experience.

Answer (score 0):

The displayBool in your directive is an attribute and doesn't inherit from your the parent scope of your html fragment. Your directive will have to use displayBool to decide whether or not to transclude the content into your directive.

```
<my-partial attr1="some text" attr2="some other text" displayBool="true"></my-partial>
```

Comment: But I have logic in my controller that sets it true/false based on some evaluation. How will this work with that?

Comment: You can bind it to your directive as a two-way bind, so when your controller changes its value, the directive's one will change too, if you set
`displayBool: '='` in your directive, it should work as expected!

Comment: @GabrielPires see the OP's code - that is exactly what he has done.

Comment: `<my-partial attr1="some text" attr2="some other text" displayBool="{{myEvaluationVariable}}"></my-partial>`

Comment: @kaveman Yes, a `$scope` function, that I have attached to a button in the HTML template (which I added to my question), never fires. I put a console log in and nothing happens on `ng-click`

Comment: Yeah, he did it right in the directive js, my bad. But he still didn't set the attribute correctly, in the HTML he should set the attribute as `display-bool="{{ myBool }}"`

Comment: @thomas well that's a whole other issue - you need to supply the scope function to the directive's isolate scope using the `&` modifier

Comment: @GabrielPires yes, I get what you're saying now.

Comment: @kaveman I have tried simply adding the line to my directive `closeAlert: '&',` (the name of the function) but that does not work. Do I need to do anything else?