# how to get data from controller to directive using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

> i try to get data from controller to directive template using angular
>   js. but it doesn't work..what's wrong with my code.

**Directive template:**

```
  <section class="col col-3 required">
       <code-input:select  ></code-input-select>
  </section>
```

**Directive Code:**

```
 gateApp.directive('codeInputSelect',function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            dtaas : '@'
        },
        template : '{{dtaas+ "uu"}}',
        link : function(scope, elem, attr){
        }
    }
})
```

**My controller:**

```
$scope.dtaas="hi welcome to ";
```

Comment: This `<code-input:select  ></code-input-select>` HTML tag doesn't make sense, is that a typo here or in your code too ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something  like:

```
<section class="col col-3 required">
    <code-input-select dtaas="dtaas" ></code-input-select>
</section>
```

Comment: in this way it's working fine..but i need to share data from controller to directive.?

Comment: you need to change the binging to two way in your directive declaration then like so: scope : {
        dtaas : '='
    } take a look at this SO question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

Answer (score 0):

You also need to declare the `dtaas` variable as a 2-way-binding - not as simple string.

```
scope : {
        dtaas : '='
    },
```