# Passing an array to a directive from a ng-repeat item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following directive:

```
var productsTable = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            products: '@'
        },

        templateUrl: '../js/app/templates/products_table.html'
    };
};
```

The template is a simple table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">
            <td><% product.id %></td>
            <td><% product.name %></td>
            <td><% product.quantity %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And it is used inside this piece of code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="entry in entries">
        <products-table products="entry.products"></products-table>
    </div>
</div>
```

An example of the `entries` variable would be:

```
var entries = [
    {
        id: 1,
        products: [
            {
                id: 1001,
                name: 'Product 1',
                quantity: 30
            },
            {
                id: 1002,
                name: 'Product 2',
                quantity: 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        products: [
            {
                id: 3001,
                name: 'Product 3',
                quantity: 450
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The problem is: the directive **does not recognize** the products array, and does not show the table.

Comment: isn't `var entries` is `$scope.entries`?

Comment: oh yes, I just gave an example of the array. The `entries` array is inside a controller...

Comment: "It does not show the table"? Do you mean the template isn't loaded at all, or that the data in the table is not displayed? If the former, have you registered your directive in your module?

Comment: @Patrick the table appears but does not show the data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
scope: {
   products: '='
},
```

also in *Angular* you should use `{{ }}` instead of `<% %>`

[`Example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAMAsU2tBUpHZlX7Y8Nu?p=preview)

Comment: I've got the point here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-bind="{{variable name}}"  in place of {{}} as an attribute in td