# Understanding the contextual usage of scope in angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I was just going through the documentation of Angular.js for **[ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)**, i came across the following example:

```
<script>
  angular.module('transcludeExample', [])
   .directive('pane', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { title:'@' },
        template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                    '<div style="background-color: gray">{{title}}</div>' +
                    '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
                  '</div>'
      };
  })
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    $scope.text = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...';
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input ng-model="title" aria-label="title"> <br/>
  <textarea ng-model="text" aria-label="text"></textarea> <br/>
  <pane title="{{title}}">{{text}}</pane>
</div>
```

I am not quite sure why these two properties are used in the directive:

```
transclude: true,
scope: { title:'@' },
```

I beleive doing `transclude: true,` gives the directive access to

```
$scope.title
$scope.text
```

which is in the controller , i am not sure about this though , but why is scope being used here ? i mean in such a weird fashion that too, I.E. ,

```
scope: { title:'@' },
```

What is the `@` there for ? so to sum up my whole question, can somebody explain to me why the  `transclude` and `scope` properties are used here in the directive ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transclude property tells angular to replace the `<ng-transclude>` tag with the HTML code inside the directive. In your case, the {{text}} string.

The property:

```
scope: { title:'@' },
```

tells angular to include the attribute title passed to the directive in its scope.

More documentation here:

[What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

and of course here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: the answer and the related links made more sense after i saw this tut on `scope` .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4JnEqlnLnE