# How to use passed data in a directive template?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I created a reusable component with directive as follows:

```
app.directive("menu", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: '/menu.html',
        scope: {
            title: '=title'
        }
    };
});
```

menu.html:

```
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

Obviously I want to pass the `title` property from outside and show is in within the `menu.html`.

Usage in main.html:

```
<div menu title="test"></div>
```

Result: the lable is not resolved. Why?

Comment: try just using -  title: '='

Comment: what does the $scope.text contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare it this way :

```
app.directive("menu", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: '/menu.html',
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        }
    };
});


Text Binding    (Prefix: @)
One-way Binding (Prefix: &) (for functions)
Two-way Binding (Prefix: =)
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) goes more deep about @ vs =

Comment: What's the difference when using `title: '@'` (which works) instead of `title: '='` (which does not work)?

Comment: @membersound added some info on my answer, I'll add the link to the angular doc as soon as i'll find it ;p

Comment: ''@" means one way binding,
"=" means two way binding

Comment: @membersound I couldn't find the official angular documentation about it, I edited my answer with a SO post that explain it. Remembering `@ for text, = for variables, & for functions` will be enough in most easy cases :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of binding with directives:

1. "@"   (  Text binding / one-way binding )
2. "="   ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )
3. "&"   ( Behaviour binding / Method binding  )

So in your case, if you only care about displaying the text you would use the '@' notation