# Using ng-blur in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am having problems with using `ng-blur` in a custom directive. What I want is to be able to make a component that can handle any type of function sent into the `ng-blur` attribute on the directive.

Here is the directive example:

```
<az-dir ng-blur="change()" lid="test" ng-model="obj.test"></az-dir>
```

Javascript directive

```
app.directive('azDir', azDir);
function azDir() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      ngBlur: '=',
      lid: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel'
  };
}
```

Simple angular controller:

```
var app = angular.module('ashtest', []);

app.controller('TopCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.obj = {
      test: "Ashkan"
    };

    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.obj.test = "changedThis";
    }


  }
]);
```

[My Plunker Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/rvmSv1xCoEp8GlVgR9Qn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ngBlur: '&',

explaining in:

1. "@"   (  Text binding / one-way binding )
2. "="   ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )
3. "&"   ( Behaviour binding / Method binding  )

[What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

Comment: Try it on my plunker, it doesn't trigger if you use '&'

Comment: <input type="text" ng-blur="ngBlur()" ng-model="ngModel" id="lid"/>

Works for me this way

Comment: Awesome! ng-blur="ngBlur()" that was what I was missing. Thanks! :)