# How to execute a method in directive which is passed through an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Goal: I need to execute a method in a directive template html , the method is a member of an object which is passed to directive scope.

I am trying to get "Hello, world!" output. Can some one help please.

html:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{obj.func1()}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = { func1: "$scope.function1.toString()" };
  
  $scoe.function1 = function() {
    return "world!";
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pass-object obj="obj"></pass-object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to define the function before you create the object.
Second you need to pass the function definition not the function call to the object(without '()').

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{obj.func1()}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.function1 = function() {
        return "world!"; // here you can call .toString() if needed
    };
    $scope.obj = { func1: $scope.function1 };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pass-object obj="obj"></pass-object>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. "@"   (  Text binding / one-way binding )
2. "="   ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )
3. "&"   ( Behaviour binding / Method binding  )

So you should user & instead of = and passing the function itself, not the whole object. I can not make work your shippet, not your directive without the function.

See more:
[What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to use "=", as I have a object with all required functions which needed in directive and also I need two-way binding. vlad's solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: { obj: '&obj' },

    template: '<div>Hello, {{obj()}}!</div>'
};
});

 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.obj = { func1: $scope.function1 };

$scope.function1 = function() {
    return "world!";
};
});

<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <pass-object obj="function1()"></pass-object>
 </div>
```

You can also pass the function in the directive and call it.. this works for me ..

Comment: Thanks Jenil. I have tried this way I, it works fine. Since I have many arguments to be passed to directive so I was planning to use a object. I was looking for a solution by explicitly passing function as part of object and call it. I got the answer from vlad.