# angularjs - update `acute.select` list after `ac-change`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `acute.select` in my `angularjs` project. I have an `array`:

```
$scope.users = [];
$scope.acuteusers =[{UserName:"john"},{UserName:"joe"},{UserName:"mary"}];

        $scope.stateSelected = function(state){
            console.log(state);
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.acuteusers.length; i++) {
                if (state.UserName == $scope.acuteusers[i].UserName) {
                    $scope.acuteusers.splice(i,1);
                };
            };
            console.log($scope.acuteusers);
        }
```

and `html`:

```
<select class="ac-select stateList" ac-model="users" ac-options="s.UserName for s in acuteusers" 
        ac-settings="{ comboMode: true, loadOnOpen: true, minWidth: '470px' }" ac-change="stateSelected(value)" >
      </select>
```

I want to take out the element from `acute.select` dropdown list everything an element is selected. But somehow it will remain as initial states(no element is deleted) even the `console.log` show it already taken out. How can I resolve that?

Comment: it's may be problem in your `ac-` . add a $timeout during splice sometimes it's take time to trigger `$digest`.

Comment: i think splice should be like $scope.acuteusers.splice(i,1);

Comment: Never modify the array while iterating over it, it is an anti-pattern. If you have to remove elements from the array while iterating over it, do it backwards (start the counter with `array.len` and decrement).

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I added `$timeout` and it still the same. It seems like `acute.select` have a set of array in its own scope.

Comment: I notice there is a `acRefresh` options. How to use that?

Answer (score 0):

After much reading about Isolated Scope for directives( [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope?rq=1), [link2](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/)), I decided to hack the `acute.select.js` directive.

First I add in a new `scope data` in `acute.select.js`:

```
.directive("acSelect", function($parse, acuteSelectService) {
    var defaultSettings = acuteSelectService.getSettings();
    return {
        restrict: "EAC",
        scope: {
            "acSettings": "@",
            "acOptions": "@",
            "model": "=acModel",
            "acChange": "&",
            "keyField": "@acKey",
            "acRefresh": "=",///I believe you can use this, but no documentation at all.
            "acFocusWhen": "=",
            "id": "@",
            data:"=acuteOptions"///newly added by me.
        },
replace: true,
        templateUrl: defaultSettings.templatePath + "acute.select.htm",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.initialise();

            ///**Then I added in $watchCollection to watch the `data` changes.
            scope.$watchCollection('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
            ///**I found out scope.allItems is the array to build and display the list. 
///however it must follow {text,value,index} object format. So I reformat it that way.
            scope.allItems = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < newVals.length; i++) {
          scope.allItems.push({text:newVals[i].UserName,value:newVals[i],index:i});
            };
            }, true);
        },
```

in `html`, add in `acute-options`:

```
<select class="ac-select stateList" ac-model="users" acute-options="acuteusers" ac-options="s.UserName for s in acuteusers" 
        ac-settings="{ comboMode: true, loadOnOpen: true, minWidth: '470px' }" ac-change="stateSelected(value)" >
      </select>
```

Now whenever `$scope.acuteuser` changes, it will change the dropdown list.

I still believe `acRefresh` can do the job, but I am just can not figure out how. It will be nice if someone can share a more robust solution.