# Angular directive with bool attribute passing string instead of bool

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that will disable all the input elements inside of the container, but I'm having trouble with the attribute.  This is what I've got for the directive

**Directive**

```
angular.module('common')
    .directive('bdDisabled', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    bdDisabled: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    attrs.$observe('bdDisabled', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                            if (newValue) {
                                element.find('input, select, button, submit, textarea').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                            } else {
                                element.find('input, select, button, submit, textarea').removeProp('disabled');
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

This is how I want to use it:

```
<div class="cg-content cg-shadow" bd-disabled="isLoading">
```

The problem is that the attribute value is the string `isLoading` and not the value.

If I wrap it in braces it breaks and I get an error in the console. 
If I wrap it in braces and change the scope to '@' instead of '=', it works. But it sends the string "true" or "false", not a boolean value.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you switch `attrs.$observe` with `scope.$watch` ?

Comment: I'll give it a try, hold on

Comment: using @ is for passing one way binding string. You may parse it to boolean, otherwise pass it as =, which will be two way binding object

Comment: @OmriAharon, that did it.  Thanks.  Please suggest it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, I'd switch the `attrs.$observe` with `scope.$watch`. On a personal preference, I'd also use the function expression instead of a string, since if you're using typescript for instance (or will use) you'll be notified if the property changes, where a string will probably remain as it is:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
      return scope.bdDisabled;
      }, 
      function (newVal, oldVal) {
          ...
      }
);
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't see the relevance to using the function in your `$watch` and TypeScript? It's possible with or without.

Comment: @ste2425 What I said was that if you're using Typescript, for instance, and set a compiler to fail on build on JS errors, then changing the variable's name you're watching will cause the build to fail if you're referencing the variable in the function (since that variable will no longer be known). If it's just written in the string, i.e., 'bdDisabled', then compilation will still succeed. That was just an example.

Comment: $watch is used when you want to watch a model or scope property. E.g in your case  bd-disabled="isLoading" , scope.$watch(attrs.bdDisabled) or scope.watch('isLoading') .  $observe will only work when you want to watch value change of a DOM attribute using interpolation  e.g  firstName= "Mr : {{firstName}}"  in your directive use attrs.$observe('firstName') in this case $scope.$watch won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use observe with '='. See the following link for details, I believe it is much more robust than the docs.

[What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

As far as your code goes, I would double check the isLoading variable to make sure it is a boolean.

Comment: Hi, it's definitely a boolean.  The reason it's being processed as a string is because of the `@`, which casts it as a string when passing it in.

Comment: @Smeegs my mistake, I was looking at your code when I read that.

Answer (score -1):

When you changed you scope definition from "=" to "@", you just want to pass the as a String, not the Two-Way-Bind mode. Sure, you can convert that to true indeed, like:

`var myBool = Boolean("false"); // === true`

`var myBool = Boolean("true"); // === true`

But be careful with that because any string can be consider as `true` like:

`var myBool = Boolean("foo"); // === true`

Comment: Boolean( 'false' ) is true

Comment: Agree, my bad, I just forgot about that JS issue, my intent was just show the scope definitions of AngularJS

Comment: Fixed, be careful when you test truthy values against strings `var myBool = Boolean("foo"); // === true`. Consider check the MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy