# Angular Filter is not working inside directive expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive i am binding the attribute and object name in expression. I need to convert both value to lowercase. i tried using  filter on that. It's not working. Even i tried using $filter service also it's not working. Please help anyone to achieve this.

Thanks in advance..

**Directive Code:**

```
 bosAppModule.directive('layoutTableCellControlControlRender',['$compile','$filter', function($compile,$filter){
    var layoutTableCellControlRenderObj={};
    linkFnTableCellControlRender=function(scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.controlData="NOCONTROLDATA";
        scope.kendoOptions={};   
        //scope.field = $filter('lowercase')(scope.field);
    };  
    layoutTableCellControlRenderObj.scope={field:"@",tranobj:"@" };
    layoutTableCellControlRenderObj.restrict='AE';
    layoutTableCellControlRenderObj.replace='true';
    layoutTableCellControlRenderObj.template="<div field={{tablecellcontrol.attributename | lowercase }} tranobj={{tablecellcontrol.objectname | lowercase}}>" +
                                            "</div>";
    layoutTableCellControlRenderObj.link = linkFnTableCellControlRender;

    return layoutTableCellControlRenderObj; 
}]);
```

Comment: Where is your filter definition?

Comment: @ChrisHermut It is inside template  field={{tablecellcontrol.attributename | lowercase }} tranobj=**{{tablecellcontrol.objectname | lowercase}}

Comment: @ChrisHermut - I hope you got my issue.

Comment: But do you get 'tablecellcontrol.attributename' value in the output correctly (without lowercase applied)? I am just checking if you have the data in place correctly

Comment: @shershen - yes i'm getting that data

Comment: @shershen If i will add filter on that like {{tablecellcontrol.attributename | lowercase }} then only it's not binding the data. it's binding same expression instead of value.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope?rq=1)

And use in that parameter **=** for those scope properties definitions for *Two-way model binding*

```
layoutTableCellControlRenderObj.scope={field:"=",tranobj:"=" };
```

Check this simplified demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/juanmendez/k6chmnch/

Comment: Yeah..two way binding is ok.  but why filter is not working in expression?

Comment: because you're not passing the value if you use @, you should use **=**

Comment: I tried using "=". Then i am getting error - Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{tablecellcontrol.attributename}}] starting at [{tablecellcontrol.attributename}}].https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Btablecellcontrol.attributename%7D%7D&p4=%7Btablecellcontrol.attributename%7D%7D

Comment: otherwise ..is it possible to use filter in ng-model?

Comment: what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve application form in two way binding. This fields i will access from factory there i will bind this field and tranobj name to control like layoutControlsFactory.ThirdPartyReadOnly=function(controlId){
  console.log("## Create ThirdPartyReadOnly");
  var template='<input  kendo-auto-complete k-options="kendoOptions" k-ng-delay="kendoOptions" ng-model="model[tranobj].rowset[0][field]">';
  return template;
 };