# Array length different in inner function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I make a custom directive. Now I pass string data from the `chips-break` attribute and convert it to an array from the `link` method. It works, but when I get the array length inside the `ng-keydown` method, it is different.

**HTML**

```html
<input-chips chips-break="32, 13, 188" style="width:80%"></input-chips>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("inputChips", inputChipsFun);

function inputChipsFun(){
  return{
    restrict : 'EA',
    scope : {
      chipsBreak : "@"
    },
    template: '<div class="chips"><div class="chips-item"></div><input type="text" ng-keydown="inputKeyDown($event, false)"/></div>',
    link : function(scope, elem, attr){
      scope.chipsBreak = scope.chipsBreak.split(",");
      console.log("Length of Chips Break First Time = "+scope.chipsBreak.length);
      
      scope.inputKeyDown = function($event, is_blur){
        console.log("Length of Chips Break Key Press = " + scope.chipsBreak.length);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

See this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/RpDwaqjS81DZlZFEzdj2?p=preview

Open inspect element console and type some things and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `'@'` it will get a string so that's why you get length == 11 because you are getting character count in `'32, 13, 188'` string.

Check this post for more details: [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

```
link : function(scope, elem, attr){
  var x = scope.chipsBreak.split(",");
  console.log("Length of Chips Break First Time = "+scope.chipsBreak.length);
  
  scope.inputKeyDown = function($event, is_blur){
    console.log("Length of Chips Break Key Press = " + x.length);
  }
}
```

If you'll do `scope.chipsBreak = scope.chipsBreak.split(",")` your `scope.inputKeyDown` (which is a function) will get initial value of `scope.chipsBreak` which is a string.

Comment: yes @Chrish but I convert string into Array so why it's treat as string in inner function