# View not updating when scope is changed inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I update the scope from a directive? Here's a sample code showing what I want.

html

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <sample-directive></sample-directive>
    {{message}}
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('sample')
    .controller('sampleController',function($scope){
        $scope.message = "Foo";
        $scope.bar = function(){
            $scope.message = "Bar";
        }
    }).directive("sampleDirective",function(){

        return {
            controller : "sampleController",
            restrict : "E",
            template : "<button type='button' ng-click='bar()'></button>"
        }
    });
```

When the button is clicked the `$scope.message` is changed to bar but the view is not updated.(answered)

Here's another scenario:

html

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController as sc">
    <sample-directive message="bar"></sample-directive>
    {{sc.message}}
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('sample')
    .controller('sampleController',function(){
       var sc = this;
       sc.message = "foo";
       sc.bar = function(){
          //change the sc.message to value that is passed to the message attribute in the sample directive
       }
    }).directive("sampleDirective",function(){
        return {
          restrict : "E",
          template : "<button type='button' ng-click='sc.bar()'></button>",
          scope : {
            message : "@"  //how can I pass this to the sc.message scope?
          }
        }
    })
```

Comment: `$scope` is undefined.

Comment: just inject `$scope in your controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't inject `$scope` into your controller.

```
.controller('sampleController',function($scope) {
  ...
}
```

You are creating two instances of your controller:
One here: `<div ng-controller="sampleController">`
The other one for the directive `controller : "sampleController"`,

Each instance will have a different $scope, so when you call bar() inside the directive, it will update $scope.message in the directive's scope, but not outside of it.

You can omit `controller : "sampleController",` then you will have only one scope. (Although your directive will only work inside `<div ng-controller="sampleController">`)

Comment: sorry but I forgot to add the $scope to the controller. I've edited the question with the included scope

Comment: omitting the controller : "sampleController" still does not update the $scope.message to bar.

Comment: @Dujndaf it definitely does here http://plnkr.co/edit/AeX3waJXKHbmnhErzR0Y?p=preview Perhaps you have isolated scope not shown but based on limited code in question this answer is correct

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry I didn't test it properly so I didn't notice the change but @ marton 's answer is definitely correct. One more thing though, how about when I'm using a controller as?

Comment: @Dujndaf, i think you will find the answer here helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

To keep the question useful for future bypassers, please do not keep expanding it, but open new ones if you have further questions.