# Image source is not binding with scope variable inside directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the below HTML, I want to inject '**src**' value from scope variable in controller.

HTML :

```
<customdir filterby="name" src="imgName"></customdir>
```

The **$scope.imgName** variable in controller has the image path.

Javascipt :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($http, $scope) {

$scope.name = 'ready';
$scope.imgName = '~/Content/arrow-right-xxl.png';

)};

app.directive('customdir', function ($compile) {
var getTemplate = function (filter) {
    switch (filter) {
        case 'ready': return '<div class="col-lg-1" id="ready">' +
                    '<img src={{src}} style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 35px" />' +
                '</div>';
        default: return '<input type="text" ng-model="filterby" />';           
    }
}
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        src: '@',
        filterby: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = $compile(getTemplate(scope.filterby))(scope);
        element.replaceWith(el);
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Use `ng-src` in the `img` tag

Comment: with above code, what is happening? does template renders with `input` element?

Comment: Yes its rendering for input element and its able to bind with **$scope.name** . But not for **imgName** for img element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your directive to this code

```
app.directive('customdir', function ($compile) {
    var getTemplate = function (filter, src) {
        switch (filter) {
            case 'ready': return '<div class="col-lg-1" id="ready">' +
                        '<img src='+src+' style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 35px" />' +
                    '</div>';
            default: return '<input type="text" ng-model="filterby" />';           
        }
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            src: '=',
            filterby: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var el = $compile(getTemplate(scope.filterby, scope.src))(scope);
            element.replaceWith(el);
        }
    };
});
```

Passing scope.filterby and scope.src direct to your directive.

Comment: Perfectly worked !! Can you explain me whats the difference in '@' and '=' of scope variables?

Comment: you can get the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14063373/1572987

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value of `imgName` like below, as you are using `@` for `src` attribute of your directive.

HTML :

```
<customdir filterby="name" src="{{imgName}}"></customdir>
```

Use `ng-src` in the `img` tag like below:

Javascript:

```
var getTemplate = function (filter) {
    switch (filter) {
        case 'ready': return '<div class="col-lg-1" id="ready">' +
                '<img ng-src="{{src}}" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 35px" />' +
                '</div>';
        default: return '<input type="text" ng-model="filterby" />';           
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<customdir filterby="name" ng-src="imgName"></customdir>
```

Comment: Thanks Sujithrao, I've tried this already. It's not working !

Comment: Its showing "Failed to load resource" if I do like the same above !