# How to correctly format data in directive using a one-way binding?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do some data manipulation using a one-way binding in my custom directive, but I receive "undefined" first time. What should I do with directive and not to use $watch ?

Example:

```html
<one val={{arr[1].value}}> </one>
<two val="arr[0].value"> </two>
```

Directives:

```js
 .directive('one', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
      val:'@'
      },
      template: '<div> 1111 {{val}} </div>' ,
      link: function (scope) {
      console.log('scope', scope.val) // SHOWS UNDEFINED BUT INSERT DATA IN TEMPLATE
      if(scope.val) scope.val = scope.val.replace(/\d/g,'')
      
      
      }
    }
  })
    .directive('two', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
      val:'='
      },
      template: '<div> 2222 {{val}} </div>' ,
       link: function (scope) {
      console.log('scope', scope.val)
      scope.val =  scope.val.replace(/\d/g,'')
      
      }
    }
  });
```

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbrKj/134/)

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the output you want?

Comment: y dont u follow the same way as u done for two?

Comment: @SaEChowdary that is why it is a doubt.

Comment: Cruzer - it doesn't matter, I just want to manipulate with data like in directive two, which uses two-way binding

Comment: @ Sa E Chowdary  - 'couse it shows me 'undefined', and it says ''replace of undefined' . Please follow JsFiddle link and look at console

Comment: okay got you....this is because the usage of @ and =,in case if @ your val not carrying to directive so you cant replace a undef and that's what your seeing console.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope-in-angularjs

Comment: you just need to use `attr.$observe` for accessing the value of one way binding,because its not connected with scope of parent .

Comment: The value is not loading when you access the value through one-way binding in directive. So, it is showing `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `attr.$observe` to access the value from one way binding change the code for link function to-

```
link: function (scope,elum,attr) {
  attr.$observe('val', function(value) { console.log('scope', scope.val) })
  //console.log('scope', scope.val)
  if(scope.val) scope.val = scope.val.replace(/\d/g,'')


  }
```

Find the update [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noc34s5t/)

Comment: i had tried this from some answers in so,but failed to place that link function properly.good work

Comment: you must be missing the sequence of parameters in the link function. by the way good to know it helped you.