# AngularJS DOM does not see Compile.Post scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my directive. It works, But when I uncomment `scope{}` - DOM elements do not see `scope.greeting`.

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                //scope:{},
                compile: function(tHtml,tAttr){
                    return {
                        post: function(scope,ele,attr){
                            scope.greeting = 'Hello!';
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

If to use the common way witk link function then all works.
At the same time I cannot use Compile and Link at the same time
What is wrong?

Comment: it's much better if we know what you want to do, maybe there is another way

Comment: I want to call from DOM elements functions in compile.post function

Answer (score 0):

When using `scope` property you are saying that you want to use an isolated scope.

Because `myDir` does not have `greeting` property defined, when you uncomment `scope` you get undefined forn `greeting`. With  `//scope: {}` you are using parent scope (which, I guess, has got `greeting` property).

See this [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope-in-angularjs).

Comment: but separate Link function works. By idea Compile.Post should return the same Link function. Ok - how to using isolated scope to  make DOM call function in post function?

Comment: Read about DDOs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object (scope section). Also you rcompile function arguments are incorrect.

Comment: Ok  - will ask another way : Compile.Post and just Link are the same? b/c I see they works differently.