# Access attributes declared inside an AngularJS component's tag

Tags: typescript, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.6

I would like to declare an attribute and assign a value to it in the component's HTML tag, like this:

```
<my-component my-attr="foo"></my-component>
```

Then I'd like to get the value of this attribute (`my-attr`) from inside my controller.

Is this possible using AngularJS 1.6 and TypeScript, and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

When defining the component, declare `myAttr` as a binding for the component. This way its value will be part of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute should be declared in the `bindings`:

```
app.component('myComponent', {
  ...
  bindings: {
    myAttr: '@'
  }
});
```

(Binding types: [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope-in-angularjs))

The name of the attribute is normalized to camelCase and the value will be set on the controller instance as a property. So you might want to declare it accordingly on your controller type:

```
class MyComponentController
{
    myAttr: string;

    logAttribute()
    {
        console.log(this.myAttr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I am not sure I can do it like this with TypeScript, it seems that I need to declare the bindings inside the constructor which complicates things for me and I don't know how to refer to this attribute after that. For example, the following would not work...

```
constructor() {
  this.bindings = {
    myAttr : '@'
  };
}

console.log(this.myAttr);
```

Comment: Bindings have to be defined during component declaration because they need to be evaluated by the Angular parser.

Comment: OK, indeed it makes sense. And then how would you refer to this? To print its value from the controller for example?

Comment: Just as you wrote by accessing `this.myAttr`. As mentioned in the answer you of course have to declare `myAttr` as a property of your class. Edited answer for clarity. (You may get an error if you use strict TS options.)