# Dynamically update a directive attribute using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular JS directive that looks something like this:

```
function ($sce) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('...'),
        scope: {
            serviceName: '@?',
        },
        controller: 'MyController',
        link: function () {}
    };
}
```

The directive is instantiated like so:

```
<my-directive service="My Cool Service"></my-directive>
```

Recently, some consumers of this directive would like the ability to modify the `service` attribute after the directive has been instantiated and have the directive reflect the change. Here is an example of what a specific consumer is doing:

```
const directive = document.querySelector('my-directive');
directive.setAttribute('service', 'Another Service Name');
```

This makes sense; however, the directive does not reflect the change once they set the attribute. I am figuring out a way to accomplish this. I have tried using `scope.$watch` and [$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) to no avail; example:

```
link: function (_, _, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe("serviceName", newValue => updateServiceName(newValue));
}
```

Any insights on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: can you create example with $observe not working? cause it should if you do things correctly

Answer (score 0):

[The `serviceName` property inside your directive's scope definition should be bound with `=` instead of `@`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope-in-angularjs). Then, from the outer code, just pass in the service name with a variable.

```js
$scope.myServiceName = "My Cool Service";
```

```html
<my-directive service="{{myServiceName}}"></my-directive>
```

Now if you change the `myServiceName` value, the change will be reflected in the child directive.

Comment: This directive is consumed by other UIs, written in different frameworks, and by other teams. So I need to be able to select the element and manually update the attribute and have the directive re-render based on that change. Would the same advice apply?